# Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm trying to draw an arrow with a bigger head than normal. Is it possible without changing the style of the line itself?

Comment: Have you checked out section 58 of the TikZ manual?

Comment: @Harald Yes, just checked. Looks perfect, but it's an overkill for my simple task. Maybe you can suggest an easier way?

Comment: Not me (not a TikZ user yet), but if there is an easier way, someone will come up with it.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen LOL you said "58" without a trace of sarcasm. That manual is bigger than most Mercedes User Manuals =P

Comment: @puk: Yes indeed, but it does have a table of contents, you know. As well as an index. When I recheck now, however, section 58 doesn't look right anymore (in the 2.1 manual). I guess stuff has been moved about in there. Sorry, I don't have the time right now to find it again. Next time, I should provide the section title as well.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

### Update 2013-02-27

This code is now superseded by the new `arrows.meta` library bundled with TikZ 3.0.0.

See an example of use in [Ignasi's answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161238/586).

---

### Update 2013-01-23

The development version of the complete code is now available on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3600356&group_id=142562&atid=752795). The old `arrowhead` key is now replaced by `arrow head` to give consistency with the other keywords in the package.

---

### Update 2012-11-13

I edited all the predefined arrow tips and those in the arrows library, except for the "almost 0d" ones (`serif cm`, `space` and all the line caps arrows) and `implies` (because I think it depends indeed on the line width), whose original code has been included for completeness, so that one can find all the previously available arrows in just a single code.

For "almost 1d" arrow tips (hooks like, and bracket like), the arrowhead value sets the height of the tip, instead of its length (for left and right variants, the height of the whole hook).

The code of the `to new` arrow has now been fixed. For 45 degrees arrows, the  amplitude of the tip is actually 45° and not 46° as in the original code.

Of course, you can use the new arrows as markings too.

I can't upload the new code because it exceeds the size limit for the answers, but I'm posting a picture of the result of the new test file. I sent an email to Till Tantau asking to turn the code in a new `TikZ` library and we'll see.

---

I'm not a `TikZ` guru, so I've done what I could. Therefore everyone is invited to improve the code, and I really think it can be improved. Save the new arrows code as `arrowsnew.tex` and load it by means of `\input{arrowsnew}` in your preamble. There are nine new arrows named `latexnew`, `latexnew reversed`, `latex'new`, `latex'new reversed`, `onew`, `squarenew`, `stealthnew`, `stealthnew reversed` and `tonew` (or `>new`). It works like this: if you call an arrow without the `arrowhead` key or you don't assign it any value, the original code is used, so that the new code can fully replace the old one. Otherwise, if you assign a value to the `arrowhead` key, the lenght of the arrowhead will be set to `<value>`. At the moment, the `tonew` arrow is slightly different from the original. Please, don't directly edit the code, but feel free to reuse/edit it in a new answer.

### The result of the new code 2012-11-13

[image]

### The old test code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\input{arrowsnew}

\tikzset{options/.code={\tikzset{#1}}} % just to compact the code

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red] (2,-24.2) -- (2,0.2) node [above right, black] {1 cm};
\draw [red] (3,-24.2) -- (3,0.2);
\foreach \x [count=\i from 0] in {
  {latex-latexnew},
  {latex-latexnew, arrowhead=1cm},
  {latex-latexnew, arrowhead=1cm, line width=1pt},
  {latex reversed-latexnew reversed, arrowhead=1cm, line width=1pt},
  {latex'-latex'new},
  {latex'-latex'new, arrowhead=1cm},
  {latex'-latex'new, arrowhead=1cm, line width=2pt},
  {latex' reversed-latex'new reversed, arrowhead=1cm, line width=2pt},
  {o-onew},
  {o-onew, arrowhead=1cm},
  {o-onew, arrowhead=1cm, line width=2pt},
  {square-squarenew},
  {square-squarenew, arrowhead=1cm},
  {square-squarenew, arrowhead=1cm, ultra thick},
  {stealth-stealthnew},
  {stealth-stealthnew, arrowhead=1cm},
  {stealth-stealthnew, arrowhead=1cm, ultra thick},
  {stealth reversed-stealthnew reversed, arrowhead=1cm, ultra thick},
  {to-tonew},
  {to-tonew, arrowhead=1cm}
}
{
  \draw [options/.expand once=\x] (0,-1.2*\i) -- (3,-1.2*\i) node [right] {\x};
}
\draw [<->new, arrowhead=0.25in, line width=4pt] (0,-24) -- (3,-24)
      node [right] {\verb!<->!new, arrowhead=0.25in, line width=4pt};  
\draw [red] (3,-23.2) ++ (-0.25in,0) -- ++(0,-1.6) node [below,black] {0.25 in}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### The result

[image]

### The old arrowsnew code (superseded)

```
% This is not an official TikZ library. Use at your own risk!

\makeatletter
% alternative latex arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclare{latexnew}{latexnew}
{
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{latexnew}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
    \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
    \fi%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{latexnew}%
    \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 10%
  \fi%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-1\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+9\pgfutil@tempdima}%
}
{
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{latexnew}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
    \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
    \fi%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{latexnew}%
    \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 10%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0bp}%
  \fi%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{9\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{6.3333\pgfutil@tempdima}{.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{2\pgfutil@tempdima}{2\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-1\pgfutil@tempdima}{3.75\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-1\pgfutil@tempdima}{-3.75\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{2\pgfutil@tempdima}{-2\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{6.3333\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{9\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

% alternative latex reversed arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclarereversed{latexnew reversed}{latexnew reversed}{latexnew}{latexnew}

% alternative latex' arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclare{latex'new}{latex'new}
{
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{latex'new}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{latex'new}%
    \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 10%
  \fi%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-4\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+6\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{latex'new}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{latex'new}%
    \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 10%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0bp}%
  \fi%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{6\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{3.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-1\pgfutil@tempdima}{1.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}{3.75\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{-1.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{1\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-1.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{-1\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}{-3.75\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{-1\pgfutil@tempdima}{-1.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{3.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{6\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

% alternative latex' reversed arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclarereversed{latex'new reversed}{latex'new reversed}{latex'new}{latex'new}

% alternative o arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclare{onew}{onew}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{onew}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=9\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.5\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdimb}%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{onew}%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by -0.5\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \fi%
}
{ 
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{onew}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=0pt%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{onew}%
    \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 9%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=0.5\pgflinewidth%
  \fi%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}%
                             {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0bp}}}%
                {4.5\pgfutil@tempdima-\pgfutil@tempdimb}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}

% alternative square arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclare{squarenew}{squarenew}
{
 \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{squarenew}=-1pt%
   \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt
   \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.275\pgflinewidth%
   \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-\pgfutil@tempdima}
   \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.5\pgflinewidth
   \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdima}
 \else%
   \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{squarenew}%
   \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 8%
   \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-7\pgfutil@tempdima}%
   \pgfarrowsrightextend{+1\pgfutil@tempdima}%
 \fi%
}
{
 \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{squarenew}=-1pt%
   \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
   \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.275\pgflinewidth%
   \pgfutil@tempdimb=0pt%
 \else%
   \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{squarenew}%   
   \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 8%
   \pgfutil@tempdimb=0.5\pgflinewidth%
 \fi%
 \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
 \pgfsetroundjoin
 \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{1\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
                            {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdimb}{-\pgfutil@tempdimb}}}
 \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{-7\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
                            {\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{-\pgfutil@tempdimb}}}
 \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{-7\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
                            {\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}}
 \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{1\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
                            {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdimb}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}}
 \pgfpathclose
 \pgfusepathqfillstroke
}

% alternative stealth arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclare{stealthnew}{stealthnew}
{
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{stealthnew}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
    \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
    \fi%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{stealthnew}%
    \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 8%
  \fi%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-3\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{stealthnew}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth%
    \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
    \fi%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{stealthnew}%
    \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 8%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0bp}%
  \fi%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

% alternative stealth reversed arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclarereversed{stealthnew reversed}{stealthnew reversed}{stealthnew}{stealthnew}

% alternative to arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclare{tonew}{tonew}
{
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{tonew}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.84pt%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by1.3\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=0.21pt%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.625\pgflinewidth%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{tonew}%
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-0.8\pgfutil@tempdima}%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+0.2\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \fi%
}
{
  \ifdim\pgfgetarrowoptions{tonew}=-1pt%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=0pt,%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfgetarrowoptions{tonew}%
    \multiply\pgfutil@tempdima by 100%
    \divide\pgfutil@tempdima by 375%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=0.4\pgflinewidth%
  \fi%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetroundcap
  \pgfsetroundjoin
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgflineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{0.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}
                         {\pgfqpoint{-2\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0bp}}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.8\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
                             {\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0bp}}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{-2.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
               {\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0bp}}}
  {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
               {\pgfqpoint{-0.5\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0bp}}}
  {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{0.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0bp}}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
               {\pgfqpoint{-0.5\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0bp}}}
  {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{-2.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{-2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
               {\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0bp}}}
  {\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
               {\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{0bp}}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}

% alias alternative to arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclarealias{<new}{>new}{tonew}{tonew}

\makeatother

% tip length code
\pgfsetarrowoptions{latexnew}{-1pt}
\pgfsetarrowoptions{latex'new}{-1pt}
\pgfsetarrowoptions{onew}{-1pt}
\pgfsetarrowoptions{squarenew}{-1pt}
\pgfsetarrowoptions{stealthnew}{-1pt}
\pgfsetarrowoptions{tonew}{-1pt}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, arrowhead/.default=-1pt, arrowhead/.code={
  \pgfsetarrowoptions{latexnew}{#1},
  \pgfsetarrowoptions{latex'new}{#1},
  \pgfsetarrowoptions{onew}{#1},
  \pgfsetarrowoptions{squarenew}{#1},
  \pgfsetarrowoptions{stealthnew}{#1},
  \pgfsetarrowoptions{tonew}{#1},
}}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Maybe you could submit it as a patch to tikz? Should be quite useful! BTW, also illustrates why one normally shouldn't touch the default arrowhead sizes... (-;

Comment: @gerrit, thank you. I'm going to add more arrowheads, then we'll see. As I told to Andrew Stacey, I don't feel up to design a new package, but I'm contacting Till Tantau and seeing if he is interested in fine tuning my code.

Comment: By the way great work!

Comment: This feature request has been changed to [“open-accepted” by Till Tantau](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/73/#abe0): “ I have been thinking about how to integrate this. It seems like a good idea that a general "arrow tip size" should be an always present arrow option, which would simplify most of the code. When I have the time, I will address arrow tips in general and then integrate this.”

Comment: I had to remove all the commas in the last code block of arrowsnew.tex, because it was causing the error "Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!"

Comment: @DanStahlke, you're right but the code you're using is now superseded. You'd better use the [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/73/) in the "Update 2013-01-23" section, where that bug has been corrected. Anyway I suggest you to have a look at the new `arrows.meta` library from the latest version of TikZ, which is an official library.

Comment: @Luigi, I was dreading figuring out how to upgrade PGF, but it turns out all I had to do is unzip a file into texmf.  The new `arrows.meta` works well.

Comment: I am, admittedly, an infrequent user of tikz, but I cannot readily see how to translate this answer into the actual action of changing the size of an arrowhead. The minimum working example is involved enough that it is difficult to follow. Could you include a true minimum work example, that simply changes the size of the arrowhead? I think the rest of it is great, and clearly quite useful, but it's a bit daunting when one comes to it just looking to make the arrow head twice the normal size...

Comment: Those are some seriously cool looking symbols!

Answer (score 168):

[`TikZ v3.0`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) (among other [new features](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153392/what-are-the-new-features-in-tikz-pgf-3-0)) includes a new `arrows.meta` library. It's probably inspired in [Luigi's library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80090/1952) and deprecates previous `arrows` and `arrows.spaced` libraries.

With this new library, it's very easy to define arrowhead parameters like length or width depending or not from line width.

```
\draw[-{Latex[length=3mm,width=5mm]}] (0,0)--(2,0);
```

will draw an arrow with a `Latex` arrowhead 3mm long and 5mm thick. All *new* arrows have changed their name which now starts with a capital letter to distinguish them from *old* names. Of course old names are still valid but they don't accept options as in previous example.

It's worth to read section "16 Arrows" in pgfmanual.

Some little examples:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (0,0)--(2,0) node[right]{\emph{Old} latex arrow};
\draw[-Latex] (0,-.5)--(2,-.5) node[right]{\emph{new} Latex arrow};
\draw[-{Latex[length=3mm]}] (0,-1)--(2,-1) node[right]{with fixed length};
\draw[-{Latex[width=3mm]}] (0,-1.5)--(2,-1.5) node[right]{with fixed width};
\draw[-{Latex[length=5mm, width=2mm]}] (0,-2)--(2,-2) node[right]{widh fixed length and width};
\draw[-{Latex[red]}] (0,-2.5)--(2,-2.5) node[right]{with colorful tip};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More examples about using `arrows.meta`:

- [Skew an Arrow in a Tikz Diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160096/skew-an-arrow-in-a-tikz-diagram)
- [Custom arrow tip with `arrows.meta` TikZ library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159249/custom-arrow-tip-with-arrows-meta-tikz-library/159298#159298)
- [Adjusting the size of an arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150721/adjusting-the-size-of-an-arrow/150739#150739)

Comment: Noobs should note that there is no space in-between the hyphen and the arrowhead: `-{Latex}`. I found out the hard way.

Comment: @ahorn Yes, this is the required syntax, a hyphen (`-`) followed and/or preceded (without any space in between) by the kind of desired tip.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps a lot. Also, are there other types of arrow head that I could use? I can not find anywhere to explain that. Thanks!

Comment: @zyy Try with `Arrow tips` section in [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=202), which is also on your system: open a command window and type `texdoc pgfmanual`.

Comment: @Ignasi That works! Appreciate!

Answer (score 71):

Here is a sample of the outward-pointing triangular tips in PGF/TikZ 2.10 (see Section 24 "Arrow Tip Library" of [the 2.10 manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{tmp}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \s in {latex,latex',stealth,triangle 90,triangle 45,angle 90, angle 60} {
    \stepcounter{tmp}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-\thetmp cm]
        \node[anchor=west] (0,0) {\texttt{\s}};     
        \draw[arrows={\s-\s}] (3,0) --++ (1,0);
    \end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrows]

If you want something more customized or more specific, read Section 82 "Arrow Tips" of  [the 2.10 manual of pgf](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf).  How much bigger and in what direction are you looking for?

Comment: How does this answers my question?

Comment: This is very useful for people like me still using 2.10 pgf version. Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

Arrow sizes change with the line width. For example for `thin` and `ultra thick` lines:

[image: thin and ultra thick arrow]

If you do not want to have the whole line thicker, you can use the decoration library to add an enlarged arrow to your path. Here are two possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
   \draw[
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[ultra thick]{>}}},
    postaction={decorate}
    ]
    (0,-0.5) -- (1,-0.5);
   \draw[
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}}},
    postaction={decorate},
    shorten >=0.4pt
    ]
    (0,-1) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: bigger arrows as decorations]

Decorations are explained in chapter 31 "Decoration Library" of the [TikZ 2.10 manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf). The `shorten >=0.4pt` in the last example shortens the line by the default line width (0.4pt) so that it does not extend over the arrow tip (though the effect is nearly invisible for normal thin lines.

Comment: decorations is definitely better than coding your own arrow.  Good answer.

Comment: Yes Decoration is lots better but how would i change the line thickness

Answer (score 39):

i just stumbled on the same problem, but those solutions didn’t fit my need. but i remembered postactions, so i came up with this:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[
        -triangle 90,
        line width=4mm,
        postaction={draw, line width=1cm, shorten >=1cm, -}
    ] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbXRg.png]

The idea is to choose a line width which yields the right arrow head, and then draw the line again with a fatter line.

Of course it only works when you need the line to be fatter than the head.

Comment: No problem. I used it to mimick minecraft’s crafting screen arrow :)

Answer (score 34):

Here is a simple example of how to change all arrow heads in a document.  On modern tikz versions, the `arrows.meta` tikz library provides a variety of customisable arrow heads and `\tikzset` can be used to set the default arrow style:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

% add the following two lines to your document to get bigger arrows
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=3mm,length=3mm]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) node[left]{from here} -- (3,1) node[right]{to here};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You just need to add the marked two lines to your TeX file to get larger arrow heads.  The size is controlled by the two parameters `width` and `length`.  For the above example, the output is as follows:
[image: output of the arrow example]

There is a variety of arrow styles to choose from; the style used in the example is called `Latex`.  Examples of relatively plain arrow styles include `Stealth`, `Straight Barb` and `Computer Modern Rightarrow`; any of these arrow styles can be used by replacing `Latex` in the above example with the corresponding style name.  See the other answers and section 16.5 "Reference: Arrow Tips" of the [TikZ and PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for a complete list of available arrow styles.

Comment: `arrows.meta` library is actually the accepted answer converted into an official library. Luigi is/was involved in the conversion. You can see the note in his answer too.

Comment: @percusse, this is good to know!  (I wrote a separate answer just because with all the information provided in the other answers, I struggled a bit to know what I should actually copy/paste into my TeX file.)

Comment: The capital letter in the arrow names is important. `latex` produces an unmodifiable arrow, while `Latex` can be modified. Same for the other styles.

Answer (score 33):

Here's an alternative approach that replaces the arrow-rendering code with a customised version which allows for an extra scale factor to be applied (with only a little more work it would be possible to make it so that you could specify some formula to apply rather than just a linear scale factor and also provide different adjustments for the start and end).  It does this by changing the line width just before the arrow is drawn and then restoring it afterwards.  (It was derived from some code I had whose aim was to draw an arrow on a `double`d line which used the *inner* line width instead of the outer one.  I thought that was from a question here but can't find it now.)

This has the obvious advantage of not needing to modify every single arrow definition!

There are two macros to modify: the one that draws the arrows and the one that shortens the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461/86}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/scalable arrows/.code={
    \let\pgf@add@arrows@as@needed=\pgf@add@scalable@arrows@as@needed
    \let\pgf@shorten@path@as@needed=\pgf@shorten@path@as@needed@for@scalable
  },
  /pgf/arrow scale factor/.initial=1,
}

\def\pgf@add@scalable@arrows@as@needed{%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/arrow scale factor}{\pgf@temp}%
  \let\pgf@restorelw=\pgfutil@empty
  \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
  \else
  \edef\pgf@restorelw{\noexpand\pgfsetlinewidth{\the\pgflinewidth}}%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgf@temp\pgflinewidth}%
  \fi
  \ifx\pgf@startarrow\pgfutil@empty%
  \else%
    \pgflowlevelobj%
      {\pgftransformarrow{\pgfpointsecondonpath}{\pgfpointfirstonpath}}
      {\pgf@startarrow}%
  \fi%
  \ifx\pgf@endarrow\pgfutil@empty%
  \else%
    \pgflowlevelobj%
      {\pgftransformarrow{\pgfpointsecondlastonpath}{\pgfpointlastonpath}}
      {\pgf@endarrow}%
  \fi%
      \pgf@restorelw%
}

\def\pgf@shorten@path@as@needed@for@scalable{%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/arrow scale factor}{\pgf@temp}%
  \let\pgf@restorelw=\pgfutil@empty
  \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
  \else
  \edef\pgf@restorelw{\noexpand\pgfsetlinewidth{\the\pgflinewidth}}%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgf@temp\pgflinewidth}%
  \fi
  \pgfprocesspathextractpoints{\pgf@arrowpath}%
  \let\pgf@arrow@next=\pgf@shorten@now%
  \ifx\pgf@shorten@start\pgfutil@empty%
    \ifx\pgf@shorten@end\pgfutil@empty%
      \ifdim\pgf@shorten@end@additional=0pt\relax%
        \ifdim\pgf@shorten@start@additional=0pt\relax%
          \let\pgf@arrow@next=\relax%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \pgf@arrow@next%
  \pgf@restorelw%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\draw[green] (2,1) -- (2,-3);
\draw[line width=4pt,->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[line width=4pt,->] (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
\draw[line width=2pt,->] (0,-2) -- (2,-2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\draw[green] (2,1) -- (2,-3);
\draw[line width=8pt,->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[line width=2pt,->] (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
\draw[line width=2pt,->] (0,-2) -- (2,-2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[scalable arrows]
\draw[green] (2,1) -- (2,-3);
\draw[arrow scale factor=2,line width=4pt,->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[arrow scale factor=.5,line width=4pt,->] (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
\draw[line width=2pt,->] (0,-2) -- (2,-2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Scalable arrows]

The first column has the scalable arrows.  The second shows what they would look like with no scaling, the third shows what they would look like with the line width to get that size arrow naturally.  The green line is to show that the shortening is correctly applied.

Comment: Ah, lazy! `=)` That's a very clever approach!

Comment: @Jake Doubly so since I had the code lying around anyway (almost).

Comment: @Jake !! I didn't answer this *for* the bounty.  The bounty reminded me that it was an open problem and one that there was considerable interest in seeing a solution.  If you do something like that again I'll have to stop answering bountied questions.

Comment: @Jake, you are very generous. I think both Andrew and I didn't reply just for the bounty, but because the challenge was very interesting. So if you didn't assign it yesterday, it would have been the same to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Jake, as you can see, Andrew and I are on the same wavelength: I started writing before reading Andrew's comment.

Comment: @Luigi You definitely deserve the bounty.  I don't think that *anyone* really answers these *for* the bounty but bounties (for me) are a way of marking out questions for special attention.  The big difference (with regard to bounties) between our answers is that you put in a lot of work and I was lazy!  So I completely agree with Jake's decision to award it to you yesterday.  I just think it's daft to put another one on for this answer.

Comment: @Andrew, thank you too. I agree with you about the purpose of the bounties. By the way, I'm going to add more arrowheads in the next days.

Comment: @Luigi Even more reason why you deserve the bounty.  Would you consider packaging them into an upload for CTAN?

Comment: @Andrew, I don't feel up to mantain a new package. I'd be honoured if Till Tantau will check my code and use it in a new library. Otherwise, any TikZ guru (maybe you) is allowed to build a new package using my code.

Comment: @Luigi: No worries, I didn't feel like I *needed* to offer a second bounty. However, in this case I felt like both answers should be highlighted: hopefully the bright red `+500` will make it easier for others to spot these useful answers. Also, it's not really a sign of generosity: After 20000 reputation points, more points don't really mean anything. Offering them as bounties to motivate answers or to highlight existing answers is really the only way they can be put to any use.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: See my message to Luigi above

Comment: Would the drive-by downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 19):

I feel your pain there. The regular arrow head is almost invisible.
You can declare your own arrow head using `\pgfarrowsdeclare`. You can modify the example below using commands from chapters 71 and 74 of the pgf manual. This is a simpler version of the example from chapter 74, which I latexified a bit while I was at it. Hope that helps. The idea behind declaring your own length is that it's going to scale with line thickness when you do it this way.

```
\newlength{\arrowsize}  
\pgfarrowsdeclare{biggertip}{biggertip}{  
  \setlength{\arrowsize}{0.4pt}  
  \addtolength{\arrowsize}{.5\pgflinewidth}  
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{0}  
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-5\arrowsize}  
}{  
  \setlength{\arrowsize}{0.4pt}  
  \addtolength{\arrowsize}{.5\pgflinewidth}  
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-5\arrowsize}{4\arrowsize}}  
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}  
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5\arrowsize}{-4\arrowsize}}  
  \pgfusepathqstroke  
}
```

To use your arrow afterwards, say something like

```
\draw[-biggertip] (0,0) -- (0,1);
```

Comment: A useful hint could be, to take "arrows" out of the \usetikzlibrary statement. At least that did the trick for me.