# meta arrow tips

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Page 316 of the tikz-pfg manual describes meta arrow tips and says that usually we do not want to have the tip scaled the same way as the supporting line. Is there a way to keep this feature, ie, when using `line width=5pt`, the tip should be five times bigger than for `line width=1pt`?

Comment: Which version of the pgfmanual are you refering?

Comment: v1.18: maybe an old one.

Comment: pgmanual v2.10 you are refering to pag.609

Comment: If you want to produce exactly the same results as in the section of the [manual](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=609) you referred to, you may want to have a look at the code with which these were created: It is available in the file [pgfmanual-en-base-arrows.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/text-en/pgfmanual-en-base-arrows.tex). Look at the definitions of `\pgfarrowsdeclare{bad latex}` and `\pgfarrowsdeclare{bad to}`.

Comment: What can be done if I want to add parameters to arrows tip?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The v2.10 pgfmanual discusses these on Page 609.  It shows both the meta arrows and the *resized* arrows.

In the TeX code for the manual the arrow tips were coded using `pgfarrowsdeclare`.  Based on this, I would assume that there is not an existing option to simply have the arrows *resized* based on the line width. So, if you want to use them you would need to include the code shown below for the `bad latex` and `bad to` arrow styles in your document.  Then to select them instead of specifying the arrows as `[-latex]` or `[-to]` arrows, you would simply use `[-bad latex]` or `[-bad to]`.

Below is a comparison. The red arrows are *resized* according to the line size, and the blue ones are the *meta* arrows that are not simply scaled.  From the small and large line widths it is clear that the *meta arrows* produce better looking results:

[image]

Here is the code which is copied almost directly from `pgfmanual-en-base-arrows.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{soul}% for highlighting output

\begin{document}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{bad latex}{bad latex}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-1\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{9\pgflinewidth}
}
{
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{9\pgflinewidth}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpoint{6.3333\pgflinewidth}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{2\pgflinewidth}{2\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{-1\pgflinewidth}{3.75\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-1\pgflinewidth}{-3.75\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpoint{2\pgflinewidth}{-2\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{6.3333\pgflinewidth}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{9\pgflinewidth}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{bad to}{bad to}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-2\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{\pgflinewidth}
}
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.8\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
  \pgfsetroundcap
  \pgfsetroundjoin
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-3\pgflinewidth}{4\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpoint{-2.75\pgflinewidth}{2.5\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.25\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{0.75\pgflinewidth}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.25\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{-2.75\pgflinewidth}{-2.5\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{-3\pgflinewidth}{-4\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}

\newcommand*{\ArrowType}[1]{\hl{\textbf{-#1}}}%

\sethlcolor{lightgray}
These are the \emph{resized} \ArrowType{bad latex} and \ArrowType{bad to} arrows:

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=red,fill=red]
  \draw[-bad latex,line width=0.1pt] (0pt,0ex) -- +(3,0)  node[thin,right] {line width is 0.1pt};
  \draw[-bad latex,line width=0.4pt] (0pt,-2em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 0.4pt};
  \draw[-bad latex,line width=1.2pt] (0pt,-4em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 1.2pt};
  \draw[-bad latex,line width=5pt]   (0pt,-6em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 5pt};

  \draw[-bad to,line width=0.1pt] (6cm,0ex) -- +(3,0)  node[thin,right] {line width is 0.1pt};
  \draw[-bad to,line width=0.4pt] (6cm,-2em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 0.4pt};
  \draw[-bad to,line width=1.2pt] (6cm,-4em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 1.2pt};
  \draw[-bad to,line width=5pt]   (6cm,-6em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 5pt};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip\bigskip
And the standard meta \ArrowType{latex} and \ArrowType{to} arrows:

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=blue,fill=blue]
  \draw[-latex,line width=0.1pt] (0pt,0ex) -- +(3,0)  node[thin,right] {line width is 0.1pt};
  \draw[-latex,line width=0.4pt] (0pt,-2em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 0.4pt};
  \draw[-latex,line width=1.2pt] (0pt,-4em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 1.2pt};
  \draw[-latex,line width=5pt]   (0pt,-6em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 5pt};

  \draw[-to,line width=0.1pt] (6cm,0ex) -- +(3,0)  node[thin,right] {line width is 0.1pt};
  \draw[-to,line width=0.4pt] (6cm,-2em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 0.4pt};
  \draw[-to,line width=1.2pt] (6cm,-4em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 1.2pt};
  \draw[-to,line width=5pt]   (6cm,-6em) -- +(3,0) node[thin,right] {line width is 5pt};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Questions: [Is it possible to change size of arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-size-of-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf), and [How can I increase arrow-head size in tkz-graph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49009/how-can-i-increase-arrow-head-size-in-tkz-graph).