# TikZ arrowheads to match xy-pic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, xy-pic

I’d like to make arrow tips in TikZ that match with xy-pic’s standard arrowheads.  The methods from [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37320/matching-arrowheads-in-tikz-with-math-mode-arrowheads) look appropriate, but I thought I’d check first: has anyone else already created these?

(The motivation is mainly that I’d like to have TikZ and xy-pic diagrams coexisting in the same document, since I often want the flexibility of TikZ, but I have co-authors who don’t know it and prefer to write in xy-pic.)

Answer (score 4):

You should try the [tikz-cd](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) package. The package offers an arrow tip library that matches closely the arrows present in the Computer Modern typeface, which in turn match those of the xy-pic's standard arrow heads.