# Tikz arrow head same as arrows in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matching arrowheads in TikZ with math mode arrowheads](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37320/matching-arrowheads-in-tikz-with-math-mode-arrowheads)

How do I make the arrow head in latex same (or at lest very similar) to those that e.g. \leftarrow produces?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {$A \rightarrow B$};
\node (B) at (2,0) {$0$}; 
\path[->]
(B) edge[] node{} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document
```

Silly example, but I use mostly simple diagrams for which I use math-mode arrows, and occasional complicated ones for which I use tikz. It would be nice if they would look the same.

Comment: At the moment, this looks very like the question the cgnieder linked to.  Please take a look at that and see if it answers your question.  If so, that's great and we'll close this as a duplicate.  If not, please edit your question to explain why not so that we're better able to help you.