# How can I increase arrow-head size in tkz-graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tkz-graph

How can I increase the size of the head of the arrows in a `tkz-graph` graph? This question is similar to [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-size-of-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf), but requires an adaptation of the solution to `tkz-graph` specifically.

Comment: Related Question: [Meta Arrow Tips](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29485/meta-arrow-tips)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `\SetUpEdge` you could adapt the answers given in the question you mention. For example:

```
\pgfarrowsdeclare{biggertip}{biggertip}{%
  \setlength{\arrowsize}{1pt}  
  \addtolength{\arrowsize}{.5\pgflinewidth}  
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{0}  
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-5\arrowsize}  
}{%
  \setlength{\arrowsize}{1pt}  
  \addtolength{\arrowsize}{.5\pgflinewidth}  
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-5\arrowsize}{4\arrowsize}}  
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}  
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-5\arrowsize}{-4\arrowsize}}  
  \pgfusepathqstroke  
}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Vertex{a}
  \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{b}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=0]{c}
  {\SetUpEdge[style={->,>=triangle 45}]
    \Edge(a)(b)}
  {\SetUpEdge[style={->,>=biggertip}]
    \Edge(b)(c)}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]