# Arrow with two colors with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to create with TikZ a yellow arrow with black margin (border, edge).
I thought I could do this by using two arrows which lie on the top of each other, e.g. with:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.25]%
\draw[->,black,very thick](-1974*0.107pt,119*0.107pt) -- (-2258*0.107pt,820*0.107pt);%first layer, black arrow
\draw[->,yellow,thick](-1974*0.107pt,119*0.107pt) -- (-2258*0.107pt,820*0.107pt);%second layer, yellow arrow
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the code]

But I am not so satisfied with the result because the black arrow should be a bit longer.  I know I could play with the end point coordinates of the black arrow so that it fits well. But if I want to change the coordinates of my black-yellow arrow, this means I have to play again with the coordinates of the black arrow, which would cost a while.

Does anyone have a better solution? I would be glad to hear any hint.:-) Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think about creating a command with 2 arguments, to produce both arrow at the same time? Something like this: `\darrow{(0,0)}{(2,3)}`. This command automatically draw the arrows using different widths and colors and end points.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Edit 1:**  the new version of `double arrow` style requires three parameters: the *global width* and the *two colors*.

Here is a solution using `postaction` to define the new style `double arrow` (I use `stealth` arrows because doubled default arrows are not beautiful). The `postaction` option allows to redraw the arrow with different parameters (like `shorten >` to shorten the ending) :

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  double arrow/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
    -stealth,line width=#1,#2, % first arrow
    postaction={draw,-stealth,#3,line width=(#1)/3,
                shorten <=(#1)/3,shorten >=2*(#1)/3}, % second arrow
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[double arrow=1pt colored by blue and white]
(0,2) -- (1,1) arc(45:-360+45+90:.5) -- (1.25,2);

\draw[double arrow=3pt colored by blue!50!black and lime,rounded corners]
(1.5,2)  -| (2,0);

\draw[double arrow=7pt colored by black and yellow]
(0,-.1) arc(120:60:.5) arc(-120:-60:.5) -- ++(30:.5);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:** I created other styles of double arrows: `double -latex`, `double round cap-latex`, `double -stealth` and `double round cap-stealth` (original `double arrow` and `double -stealth` are the same).

Firstly a small bunch:

[image: second example]

Then the code (with the four styles of double arrows):

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
  double -latex/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{    
    -latex,line width=#1,#2,
    postaction={draw,-latex,#3,line width=(#1)/3,shorten <=(#1)/4,shorten >=4.5*(#1)/3},
  },
  double round cap-latex/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{    
    round cap-latex,line width=#1,#2,
    postaction={draw,round cap-latex,#3,line width=(#1)/3,shorten <=(#1)/4,shorten >=4.5*(#1)/3},
  },
  double round cap-stealth/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
    round cap-stealth,line width=#1,#2,
    postaction={round cap-stealth,draw,,#3,line width=(#1)/3,shorten <=(#1)/3,shorten >=2*(#1)/3},
  },
  double -stealth/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
    -stealth,line width=#1,#2,
    postaction={-stealth,draw,,#3,line width=(#1)/3,shorten <=(#1)/3,shorten >=2*(#1)/3},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \size [
evaluate=\size as \width using \size,
evaluate=\size as \bend using (\size-7)*5,
evaluate=\size as \angle using \size*36+180,
evaluate=\angle as \angleplushalf using \angle+18,
] in {1,2,...,10}{
  \draw[double round cap-stealth=\width pt colored by green!50!black and lime]
  (0,0) ++(\angle:1.2) to[bend right=\bend] ++(\angle:3);

  \draw[double round cap-latex=\width pt colored by black and yellow]
  (0,0) ++(\angleplushalf:1.2) to[bend right=\bend] ++(\angleplushalf:3);
}

\foreach \size [
evaluate=\size as \width using \size,
evaluate=\size as \bend using (\size-7)*5,
evaluate=\size as \angle using \size*36,
evaluate=\angle as \angleplushalf using \angle+18,
] in {1,2,...,10}{
  \draw[double -stealth=\width pt colored by blue!50!black and white]
  (0,-9) ++(\angle:1.2) to[bend right=\bend] ++(\angle:3);

  \draw[double -latex=\width pt colored by red and yellow]
  (0,-9) ++(\angleplushalf:1.2) to[bend right=\bend] ++(\angleplushalf:3);
}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much better solution than mine for the `-stealth` arrow type.

Comment: @PeterGrill You're right: I cheated to avoid defining a new arrow. ;-)

Comment: Very nice and even easy solution! Thank you sooo much! 
I am satisfied to 99% with this solution. I would be satisfied to 100% if the beginning of the arrow would have a black margin too (as in @Peter Grill approach). Do you know if this can be added in an easy way to your code?

Comment: @partial81 I edited my answer to add details...

Comment: That is indeed fantastic! Thank you first for adapting your solution! And thanks for the other style of double arrows (the `.spaced` in the 3rd line is not needed?)! They are very nice! I think/hope that a lot of other users will benefit from your solution! Thanks again so much!

Comment: I must say 'thanks for these beautiful examples'.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks for this elegant solution! Would it be possible to add `opacity` to the first line only?

Comment: @sergej Arrows with draw or fill opacity are broken.

Comment: This is fantastic. I didn't know about `style args`. Is that in the manual somewhere? (As opposed to e.g. `style n args`.)

Comment: @cfr `style args` is in the manual... just before `style n args`!

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how I missed that....

Comment: Unfortunately, the postaction-and-shorten trick works extremely badly with bended arrow tips, since the bending amount changes with arrow tip lenght. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @Sebastian Ask a new question (with reference to this one)...

Answer (score 10):

One way would be to use `draw=black, double=yellow, double distance=2pt, ->` which draws two lines, but the result is not quite what is desired as the arrow does not get the double line:

[image]

The second uses the `bad to` style as discussed in [meta arrow tips](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29485/meta-arrow-tips/30407#30407) which provides better results:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring} 
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{bad to}{bad to}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-2\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{\pgflinewidth}
}
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.6\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
  \pgfsetroundcap
  \pgfsetroundjoin
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-3\pgflinewidth}{4\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpoint{-2.75\pgflinewidth}{2.5\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.25\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{0.75\pgflinewidth}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.25\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{-2.75\pgflinewidth}{-2.5\pgflinewidth}}
  {\pgfpoint{-3\pgflinewidth}{-4\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}

\newcommand*{\LineWidth}{5.0pt}%
\newcommand*{\InnerFactor}{0.60}% percentage shrinkage in line width
\newcommand*{\FudgeFactor}{0.30}% adjust shorten amounts
\NewDocumentCommand{\DoubleArrow}{%
    O{}% #1 = any parmaters to apply to outer drawing (optional)
    O{}% #2 = any parmaters to apply to inner drawing (optional)
    m  % #3 = start of arrow
    m  % #4 = end of arrow
     %    
    }{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\InnerLineWidth}{\InnerFactor*\LineWidth}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ShortenAmount}{\FudgeFactor*(\LineWidth-\InnerLineWidth)}%
    %
    \tikzset{outer line style/.style={%
        black,  line width=\LineWidth, -to, #1}
    }%
    \tikzset{inner line style/.style={%
        yellow, line width=\InnerLineWidth, -bad to, 
        shorten >= \ShortenAmount, shorten <= \ShortenAmount, #2}
    }%
    %
    \draw [outer line style] (#3) -- (#4);% outer layer
    \draw [inner line style] (#3) -- (#4);% inner layer
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [very thick, draw=black, double=yellow, double distance=2pt, ->] (0,1) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \DoubleArrow{0,0}{2,0}
    \DoubleArrow[blue][red]{3,0}{4,1}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is also a nice solution, although the code was quite difficult to understand. I like it much that your arrows have a black margin at their beginning! But it is a bit complicated and time consuming that one has to type the coordinates each time for the black as for the yellow arrow.
Anyway, thanks for this very good approach!

Comment: @partial81: Have defined a macro so that you don't have to repeat the coordinates.

Comment: Wow, thanks for defining this macro. Now your solution is very nice and easy to handle too! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

It is not so beautiful but it works.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\newcommand{\darrow}[2]{%
 \draw[->,black,line width=1.6pt] #1 -- #2;
 \draw[->,yellow,line width=1pt,scale=0.98] #1 -- #2;
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.25]%
\darrow{(0,0)}{(1,1)}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Or you can use your line width.

Comment: Can you add an image, and the complete code that generates it. I am not quite getting the desired results when I try to use this with `\darrow{(0,3)}{(2,3)}`.

Comment: Please, read below. There are 2 professional solutions. But I'll edit my post.

Comment: +1 for the attempt... But try your proposition with an arrow between (3,3) and (0,6) for example (scaling is centered at (0,0))!

Comment: Thanks for this post! It is a nice try to solve my problem too, but if I change the coordinates of your `darrow`, I do not always get a nice result. Anyway, thanks for trying to give a solution!