# how to add tip for a curve to make it look likes an arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I would like to draw a filled arrow around a circle. So far my picture is

[image]

I need to add tip at the end of the green curve in the above picture. I would like to be able to add tips for either sides. How can I do that.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,arrows, positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}



\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=3cm,>=stealth']
\coordinate (O) at (5,0);

\draw [very thick,fill=blue,fill opacity=.1] 
( 5, 0) circle (2.0cm) node [opacity=1] {B} ;

\draw[fill=green]
($(O) + (0:23mm)$) arc (0:180:23mm) -- ($(O) + (180:24mm)$) arc (180:0:24mm) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw[fill=green,->]`? and use `<-` for the other way?

Comment: @cfr, I've tried this but no luck.

Comment: Because it is a closed path, I think. If you draw it as a single path, it should work. See below for an example.

Comment: Did you read [Arrow with two colors with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72784/arrow-with-two-colors-with-tikz)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: double arrow in green]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=3cm,>={Stealth[width=4mm, length=6mm, fill=green]}]
    \coordinate (O) at (5,0);

    \draw [very thick,fill=blue,fill opacity=.1]
    ( 5, 0) circle (2.0cm) node [opacity=1] {B} ;

    \draw[double=green, double distance=1mm, <->]
    ($(O) + (0:23.5mm)$) arc (0:180:23.5mm);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

If you have an old version of TiKZ, the above will not work. In that case, you should either update your TeX distribution (recommended) or, if you're unable to do that, try this instead:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=3cm,>=stealth']
    \coordinate (O) at (5,0);

    \draw [very thick,fill=blue,fill opacity=.1]
    ( 5, 0) circle (2.0cm) node [opacity=1] {B} ;

    \draw[double=green, double distance=1mm, <->, green]
    ($(O) + (0:23.5mm)$) arc (0:180:23.5mm);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: older double green arrows]

Comment: I'm getting this error `! I can't find file tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex.`

Comment: @CroCo You have an old version of TiKZ. You can use `arrows` and just adapt the syntax. I only used `arrows.meta` because that's what I know and I'm not familiar with the configuration for the tips from `arrows`.

Comment: @CroCo See edit. The second version just uses the older `arrows` library and should work.

Comment: I've updated TiKz and now it is working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Here is solution (using my answer to [Arrow with two colors with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72784/arrow-with-two-colors-with-tikz)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\tikzset{
  double arrows/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
    >=stealth,
    <->,line width=#1,#2, % first arrow
    postaction={draw,<->,#3,line width=(#1)/3,
                shorten <=2*(#1)/3,shorten >=2*(#1)/3}, % second arrow
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (5,0);

\draw [very thick,fill=blue,fill opacity=.1] 
(O) circle (2.0cm) node [opacity=1] {B} ;

\draw[double arrows=1.5mm colored by black and green]
($(O) + (0:23mm)$) ++(0,-1.5mm) -- ++(0,1.5mm) arc (0:180:23mm) -- ++(0,-1.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```