# Tikz railway tracks issue in TeX Live 2021

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, texlive-2021

Until I upgraded to TeX Live 2021, I was very happy with [Mark Wibrow's train tracks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198114/101494). However, under TeX Live 2021, I get very strange behavior; the code from his answer now typesets as the following.

[image: Broken railway tracks]

I get similarly strange behavior with [cfr's version of the tracks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418299/101494).

[image: Different broken railway tracks]

I've tested the tracks on both TeX Live 2019 and 2020, and they are fine. How can I update this code to work with TeX Live 2021?

Comment: Looks like the first example has strange behavior with xelatex in TeX Live 2018, 2019, 2020, and 2021.

Comment: It seems  Mark Wibrow's code relied on a [typo in `pgf`'s driver](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/dd5892b6849f5d671dc2f882f6456a1663301cec), which has been fixed since v3.1.6a (Sep 29, 2020). On the other way, I found the problem is that, in env `tikzfadingfrompicture`,`\pgfsetpath\pgfdecoratedpath` gets the last, not the "current" path.

Comment: A nitpick: railroad ties don't cross like that on a junction. Instead, unifying wider ties should be used near the junction point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment of muzimushi the old code depended on a typo which forced pgf to resave the fadings. You can get a similar effect by using a counter:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,fit,fadings}
\newcounter{tracks}
% Layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{sleeper}
\pgfdeclarelayer{rail}
\pgfsetlayers{sleeper,rail,main}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{tracks}{final}{%
\state{final}{%
  \pgftransformreset% <- I think is possibly vital.
  %
  % Get bounding box of decorated path as a node.
  % Must do it this way using basic layer.
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current path bounding box}{south west}}%
  \pgfcoordinate{@1}\pgfpointorigin%
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current path bounding box}{north east}}%
  \pgfcoordinate{@2}\pgfpointorigin%
  \node [fit=(@1)(@2), inner sep=\railsep+2*\railwidth] (@@) {};
  %
  % Create a fading for the track.
  \pgfinterruptpicture%
    \stepcounter{tracks}% 
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tracks\thetracks]
    \path[draw=transparent!0, line width=\railsep+2*\railwidth,
     postaction={draw=transparent!100, line width=\railsep}]
      \pgfextra{\pgfsetpath\pgfdecoratedpath};
    \useasboundingbox (@@.south west) (@@.north east);
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
  \endpgfinterruptpicture
  %
  % Draw sleepers.
  \ifx\sleeperlayer\emptylayer\else\pgfonlayer{\sleeperlayer}\fi%
  \draw [draw=\sleepercolor,line width=\sleeperlength, dash pattern=on \sleeperwidth off \sleepersep, every sleeper/.try]
    \pgfextra{\pgfsetpath\pgfdecoratedpath};
  \ifx\sleeperlayer\emptylayer\else\endpgfonlayer\fi%
  %
  % Draw the track
  \ifx\raillayer\emptylayer\else\pgfonlayer{\raillayer}\fi%
  \fill [path fading=tracks\thetracks, fit fading=false,
    fading transform={shift=(@@.center)}, fill=\railcolor]
   (@@.south west) rectangle (@@.north east);
   \ifx\raillayer\emptylayer\else\endpgfonlayer\fi%
}
}
\def\emptylayer{}
\tikzset{%
  track/.style={
    decoration=tracks, decorate
  },
  decorations/.cd,
    rail sep/.store in=\railsep,
    rail width/.store in=\railwidth,
    rail color/.store in=\railcolor,
    rail layer/.store in=\raillayer,
    sleeper sep/.store in=\sleepersep,
    sleeper width/.store in=\sleeperwidth,
    sleeper length/.store in=\sleeperlength,
    sleeper color/.store in=\sleepercolor,
    sleeper layer/.store in=\sleeperlayer,
    rail sep=4pt,
    rail width=1pt,
    rail color=black,
    rail layer=rail,
    sleeper sep=6pt,
    sleeper width=1pt,
    sleeper length=10pt,
    sleeper color=gray,
    sleeper layer=sleeper,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [track] (-2,5) to (0,5) to[out=  0,in=270] (2,8);
\draw [track] (6,5) to (4,5) to[out=180,in=270] (2,8) to (2,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]