# Why does pgfkeys' value not be able to use directly

Tags: pgfkeys

The following code describes my questions about the use of `pgfkeys`'s value which puzzles me long. Anybody can give me a hand?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{%
  /path/.cd,
  color/.code=#1,
}

\pgfkeys{/path/.cd,color=yellow} %typeset "yellow" as desired

\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color} %get nothing, typeset "yellow" is wanted

\color{\pgfkeys{/path/.cd,color=yellow}} %\color{yellow} is desired,but fail to compile

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the key with `\pgfkeyssetvalue`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{%
  /path/.cd,
  color/.code=#1,
}

\pgfkeyssetvalue{/path/color}{yellow}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color} 

\color{\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color}}{x} %
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM**: I am not sure I understand your question in the comments. `\color` does not use pgfkeys. What you can do, however, is to use `.store in`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{%
  /path/.cd,
  color/.code=#1,
  mycolor/.store in=\mycolor
}

\pgfkeyssetvalue{/path/color}{yellow}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color} 

\color{\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color}}{x}

\pgfkeys{path/mycolor=red}
\color{\mycolor}{hello}

\end{document}
```

Of course, in the example at hand there is not much benefit, however in other situations in which you work with, say, Ti*k*Z commands which use pgfkeys [like here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432143/121799) there is.

Comment: Thank you marmot, I just corrected my code to get a complete Latex code block(that is, \begin{document}, and xcolor package). Yet \color{\pgfkeyssetvalue{/path/color}{yellow}} still does not work.

Comment: @lyl With `\pgfkeyssetvalue` and `\pgfkeysgetvalue` it works as expected.

Comment: if a calling of macro like this: \mycolor{color=yellow}, how to use \pgfkeyssetvalue and \pgfkeysgetvalue except for "color/.code=\color{#1}, but \color{pgfkeys' macro}?

Comment: @lyl I made an update. Are you by chance looking for `.store in` such that you can access the value without pgfkeys?

Comment: Thank you marmot! This make me learn a new way to store  value in a key.

Comment: then \pgfkeys{color/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{color}{#1}}. Is the "color" of "color/.code" the same as "color" of "\pgfkeyssetvalue{color}"?

Comment: @lyl No. Code can contain all sorts of real codes, not just a "fake code" which consists just of a string.

Comment: After that, \pgfkeys{color=blue}, which "color" is funtional, the former or the latter?

Comment: @lyl Sorry, was offline. After *what*? And what do you dislike about `store in`?

Comment: After  that means after \pgfkeys{color/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{color}{#1}}， then \pgfkeys{color=blue}. Which "color" is funtional, the color/.code or the \pgfkeyssetvalue{color}? And for "store in", anoter macro has to be defined which I don't like that.

Comment: @lyl The syntax `\pgfkeys{color/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{color}{#1}}` doesn't seem right to me (but I haven't tried it). So I probably misinterpret your question, I thought the aim is to make the key available to commands that are not using pgf keys.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit more complicated:

A code key (`/path/some key/.code=`) executes the code between `=` and `,` with the given value as parameter (`#1`). Normally it has no value, so `\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/some key}` will give out nothing (see 7 and 8). A value key can be set with `another key/.initial=initial value`. It will be given out with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/another key}` (see 9) or with `\pgfkeys{/path/another key}` (see 3). But `\pgfkeys{/path/another key=another value}` will just set the value, overwriting the old one, and give out nothing (see 6).

A code key can have a default value (`path/some key/.default=`), which will be used, if no value is given (see 2). This default will not be changed, if the key is called with a value given.

With `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/path/some key}{value}` a value can be assigned to the code key (see 10). After that, `\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/some key}` will deliver this value (see 11). But `\pgfkeys{/path/some key=something}` will still execute the code with the given value as parameter. Nevertheless, this will not change the value set with `\pgfkeyssetvalue` (see 13).

A more common example for a code key is `color d` (see 14) in the code below.

Here some example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfkeys{%
  /path/.cd,
  color a/.code=#1,
  color b/.code=#1,
  color b/.default=red,
  color c/.initial=blue,
  color d/.code={\color{#1}},
}

\parindent0pt\parskip1ex
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \verb|\pgfkeys{/path/color a}|: \pgfkeys{/path/color a}\\
      (executes given code with empty parameter)
\item \verb|\pgfkeys{/path/color b}|: \pgfkeys{/path/color b}\\
      (executes given code with default value as parameter)
\item \verb|\pgfkeys{/path/color c}|: \pgfkeys{/path/color c}\\
      (gives out initial value)
\item \verb|\pgfkeys{/path/color a=yellow}|: \pgfkeys{/path/color a=yellow}\\
      (executes given code with ``yellow'' as parameter)
\item \verb|\pgfkeys{/path/color b=green}|: \pgfkeys{/path/color b=green}\\
      (executes given code with ``green'' as parameter)
\item \verb|\pgfkeys{/path/color c=cyan}|: \pgfkeys{/path/color c=cyan}\\
      (just sets a new value)
\item \verb|\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color a}|: \pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color a}\\
      (key has no value)
\item \verb|\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color b}|: \pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color b}\\
      (key has no value)
\item \verb|\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color c}|: \pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color c}\\
      (gives out the last value stored)
\item \verb|\pgfkeyssetvalue{/path/color a}{blue}|: \pgfkeyssetvalue{/path/color a}{blue}\\
      (sets a value)
\item \verb|\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color a}|: \pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color a}\\
      (now key has a value)
\item \verb|\pgfkeys{/path/color a=yellow}|: \pgfkeys{/path/color a=yellow}\\
      (still executes given code with ``yellow'' as parameter)
\item \verb|\pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color a}|: \pgfkeysvalueof{/path/color a}\\
      (but the value has not changed)
\item \verb|\pgfkeys{/path/color d=magenta}|: \pgfkeys{/path/color d=magenta}\\
      (executes given code, which switches to the given color)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And its result:

[image]

Comment: @ Mike thank you so much for your detail explanation. I'd like review the item 8 and 9. In item 9, color c get its value for the reason of item 6. Then why does in item 8, color b not get its value by item 5?

Comment: @lyl Since `color b` is a code key, it gets executeted in item 5. But as a normal code key it has no value. The value `green` is used as parameter for the execution (see result of 5), but not stored anywhere.

Comment: Then what about /.initial? It's code or set value of a key? Why is this wrong--\pgfkeys{color/.initial=red} \color{\pgfkeysvalueof{color}}

Comment: @lyl `\pgfkeysvalueof` needs a full path for the key, starting with `/`. So `\color{\pgfkeysvalueof{/color}}` works.