# use tikz shapes.arrows as path

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am trying to reproduce this picture using tikz:[image]

My mwe is (Only the CPU box):

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur, shapes.arrows}
\synctex=1
% \usepackage{listings}%, fancyvrb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{sblock} = [rectangle, draw, %fill=Apricot!70, 
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=0em, node distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=Apricot!70, 
text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=0em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
minimum height=2em]

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.85]
      \node[block, text width=1cm, rounded corners= 0ex, draw= none]at (-1.3,0) (cpu1)
      {PC};
      \node[block, text width=3cm, rounded corners= 0ex, draw= none] at (0,
      -2)(cpu2){BUS Interface};
      \node[block, text width=1cm, rounded corners= 0ex, draw = none, text
      height=1.5cm]at (.3,0) (cpu3) {Register file}; 
      \node[block, text width=1cm, rounded corners= 0ex, draw= none,
      text height=2cm] at (3, 0) (cpu3){ALU};

      \node[double arrow, fill=Black, rotate=90] at
      (0,-2){\phantom{aa}};
      \node[single arrow, fill=Black] at
      (1.5,-.2){\phantom{aa}};
      \node[single arrow, fill=Black, rotate=180] at
      (1.5,.72){\phantom{aaa}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is I am placing the arrows as node, and that is not working. The output of the mwe is:

[image: here]

How can I place the arrows in proper way? e.g. can I use the arrow as path?

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you aware of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432147/121799)? (If you have a second, you could also have a quick look at the partner answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use arrows as paths.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=Apricot!70,
text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners=0pt, minimum height=0em}}
\tikzset{arw/.style={>={Triangle[length=3mm,width=5mm]},line width=2mm,draw=gray}}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.85]
        \node[block, text width=1cm, draw= none]at (-1.3,0) (cpu1){PC};
        \node[block, text width=1cm, minimum height=2cm, draw = none, right=0.5cm of cpu1] (cpu3) {Register file};
        \node[block, text width=3cm, draw= none, below=0.7cm of cpu3] (cpu2){BUS Interface};
        \node[block, text width=1cm, minimum height=2cm, draw= none,right=1cm of cpu3]  (cpu4){ALU};
        \draw[arw,<->] (cpu3.south|-cpu2.north) -- (cpu3);
        \draw[arw,->] (cpu3.340) -- (cpu4.200);
        \draw[arw,<-] (cpu3.20) -- (cpu4.160);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot I thought this is what OP was asking for. The question that you mentioned also makes sense. Thanks for the `arrows.meta` suggestion, with that it looks better. :)

Answer (score 0):

To use the nodes and their shape as if they were figures drawn on the path, you can use the **relative placement** of the nodes relative to each other. To do this, simply use the syntax of the `positioning` library you have already loaded.

Thus, instead of anchoring each node to a specific coordinate point, it is sufficient to use the key `right =` `below =` `below left=`, etc.

See page 229 of manual 3.0.1a.

I slightly cleaned up the code of the superfluous:
for example, you specify `draw=none` for each `block` call. Just delete the draw key in the style of the node.  But I'm far from having written everything correctly, for example, the `\tikzstyle` syntax is obsolete.

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=Apricot!70, 
text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=0em]
```

Etc.

This is only a first sketch that you need to rework to your liking. I changed some colors to make it easier for you to read this new code.

Sketch and code:

[image: sketch]

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur, shapes.arrows}
\synctex=1
% \usepackage{listings}%, fancyvrb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{sblock} = [rectangle, draw, %fill=Apricot!70, 
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=0em, node distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, fill=Apricot!70, text centered]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
minimum height=2em]

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.85]
      \node[block, text width=1cm, ]at (-1.3,0) (cpu1)
      {PC};
      \node[block, text width=1.2cm,  text height=1.5cm,right=5mm of cpu1](cpu2) {Register file}; 
      \node[block, text width=1cm, ,text height=2cm,right=1.5 of cpu2] (cpu3){ALU};

      \node[double arrow, fill=Black, rotate=90,below = 6mm of cpu2] (double-arrow)
      {\phantom{aa}};
     \node[single arrow, fill=blue,above right=-20mm and 5mm of cpu2] (single-arrow){\phantom{aa}};
      \node[single arrow, fill=red, rotate=180,above right=-5mm and 10mm  of cpu2] {\phantom{aaa}};

      \node[block, text width=3cm, below=1cm of cpu2,below left= 4mm and -3mm of double-arrow] (cpu4){BUS Interface};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```