# Drawing text in between arrows using TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi dear TeX community!

I hope you can help me out a bit with some matrices I have drawn (with the community's help of course) using the TIKZ package.

I think that I need to post almost the whole code so that you get an appropriate picture of the problem, so sorry for that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\newcommand{\mb}[1]{{\bullet #1}} % mean with bullet; dbl brackets to maintain subscript
\newcommand{\xq}{\bar{x}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat1) {
  x_{11} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{1j} & \ldots & x_{1k} \\ 

  x_{22} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2j} & \ldots & x_{2k} \\ 

  \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\ 

  x_{i1} & x_{i2} & \ldots & x_{ij} & \ldots & x_{ik} \\ 

  \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\

  x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \ldots & x_{nj} & \ldots & x_{nk} \\

};

\matrix[matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter= ), below=7em of 

mat1, xshift=-8em] (mat2) {

  \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\

  \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\

  \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\

  \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\

  \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\

  \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
};

\node[anchor=west] at (mat2.south east){$\overline{x}_{\bullet \bullet} $};


\matrix[matrix of math nodes, right=4em of mat2, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat3) {
  r_{11} & r_{12} & \ldots & r_{1j} & \ldots & r_{1k} \\

  r_{21} & r_{22} & \ldots & r_{2j} & \ldots & r_{2k} \\

  \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\

  r_{i1} & r_{i2} & \ldots & r_{ij} & \ldots & r_{ik} \\

  \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\

  r_{n1} & r_{n2} & \ldots & r_{nj} & \ldots & r_{nk} \\

};

\foreach \X/\Y in {2/{\mathrm{IN}},3/{\mathrm{ZW}}}

{\draw[-latex] (mat1) -- (mat\X);

 \draw[-latex] (mat\X.south) -- ++ (0,-4em) node[below] (G\X) 

               {$\widehat{\sigma}^2_{\Y}$};}

 \path (mat2) -- (mat3) node[midway]{$+$} (G2) -- (G3) node[midway,below=3.5em] 
(F) 

{$ \displaystyle 

F = \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{ZW}}}

         {\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{IN}}}

  = \frac{\frac{1}{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\xq_\mb{j} - \xq_{\bullet

\bullet})^2}


         {\frac{1}{N-k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (  x_{ij}   - \xq_{\bullet 
j}      )^2} 

$};

\foreach \X/\Y in {2,3}

{\draw[-latex] (G\X) -- (F);}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So the questions that I have are

1.) Is it possible to insert this equation centered **in between** the uppermost two arrows?

and

2.) to draw a **red** "double-arrow" going from `$\bar{x}_{\bullet 1}$ to $\bar{x}_{\bullet \bullet}$` and one from `$r_{11}$ to \bar{x}_{\bullet 1}`?

Thank you guys so so much!

This is what it looks like at the moment: 
[image]

This is the output I kind of imagined (roughly): 
[image: Desired output (roughly)]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For the first request, which formula are you referring to? Also how should the red line be placed? I hope if you could you paint or another program to show us the desired output (make it rough, it doesn't need to be fancy, but meaningful) :)

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).  @Ñako surely deserves a tick after all of the work that they have put in!

Answer (score 5):

## ***Further attempts with full information***

## My fourth attempt:

Customizing arrows style.

There are many ways to costumize the arrow style with `tikz`, see the [documentation](https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), Chapter 16 (p.186). In this case, by editing the `double arrow/.style` in the preamble and/or the options of the last two `draw` commands of the code you can display "more elegant" arrows:

- custom-based `double-headed arrow`:

  [image]

  Code:

  ```
  % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72793/89320, customize for double-headed arrows
  \tikzset{
  double arrow/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
      stealth-stealth,line width=#1,#2, % first arrow
      postaction={draw,stealth-stealth,#3,line width=(#1)/3,
          shorten <=2*(#1)/3,shorten >=2*(#1)/3}, % second arrow
    }
  }
  ```

  ---

  ```
    \draw[double arrow=2pt colored by red and white!80!, opacity=0.75,] (mat2-1-1.north) to [in=80,out=30]  (xpp.north);
    \draw[double arrow=2pt colored by red and white!80!, opacity=0.75,] ([yshift=2pt]mat3-1-1.north) to [in=20,out=160] (mat2-1-1.north);
  ```
- `double` and `<->`:

  [image]

  Code:

  ```
  \draw[red, double,<->] (mat2-1-1.north) to [in=80,out=30]  (xpp.north);
  \draw[red, double,<->] ([yshift=2pt]mat3-1-1.north) to [in=20,out=160] (mat2-1-1.north);
  ```

  - `double` and `Latex-Latex`:

    [image]

  Code:

  ```
  \draw[red, {Latex[length=2mm, width=2mm]}-{Latex[length=2mm, width=2mm]} ,double, double distance=.5pt] (mat2-1-1.north) to [in=80,out=30]  (xpp.north);
  \draw[red, {Latex[length=2mm, width=2mm]}-{Latex[length=2mm, width=2mm]} ,double, double distance=.5pt] ([yshift=2pt]mat3-1-1.north) to [in=20,out=160] (mat2-1-1.north);
  ```

## My third attempt:

The desired output is yet known:

- No need of `tikznode`, cell matrix referencing solution given by [Andrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495959/89320) and also in the comments by [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex)
- `double arrow/.style` taken from [Arrow with two colors with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72793/89320)

Here is my approach:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, calc,fadings}

\newcommand{\mb}[1]{{\bullet #1}} % mean with bullet; dbl brackets to maintain subscript
\newcommand{\xq}{\bar{x}}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72793/89320
\tikzset{
    double arrow/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
        -stealth,line width=#1,#2, % first arrow
        postaction={draw,-stealth,#3,line width=(#1)/3,
            shorten <=(#1)/3,shorten >=2*(#1)/3}, % second arrow
    }
}
%---------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix [anchor=center,matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat1) {
      x_{11} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{1j} & \ldots & x_{1k} \\ 
      x_{22} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2j} & \ldots & x_{2k} \\ 
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\ 
      x_{i1} & x_{i2} & \ldots & x_{ij} & \ldots & x_{ik} \\ 
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \ldots & x_{nj} & \ldots & x_{nk} \\
    };


    \matrix[anchor=center,matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter= ), below=7em of mat1, xshift=-8em] (mat2) {
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
      \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
      \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
    };

    \node[anchor=west] (xpp) at (mat2.south east){$\overline{x}_{\bullet \bullet} $};


    \matrix[anchor=center,matrix of math nodes, right=4em of mat2, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat3) {
      r_{11} & r_{12} & \ldots & r_{1j} & \ldots & r_{1k} \\
      r_{21} & r_{22} & \ldots & r_{2j} & \ldots & r_{2k} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      r_{i1} & r_{i2} & \ldots & r_{ij} & \ldots & r_{ik} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      r_{n1} & r_{n2} & \ldots & r_{nj} & \ldots & r_{nk} \\
    };

    \coordinate (aux) at ($ (mat1) !.5! (mat2) $);
    \node[anchor=center,](xij) at (mat1 |- aux) {$ \displaystyle 
        x_{ij}=\xq_\mb{j}+r_{ij}$};
    \node[anchor=center, below =-2pt of xij] (rij) {$ \displaystyle
        r_{ij}=\xq_\mb{j}-x_{ij}$};
    %
    \foreach \X/\Y in {2/{\mathrm{IN}},3/{\mathrm{ZW}}}
    {\draw[-latex] (mat1) -- (mat\X); 
    \draw[-latex] (mat\X.south) -- ++ (0,-4em) node[below] (G\X) {$\widehat{\sigma}^2_{\Y}$};}
    \path (mat2) -- (mat3) node[midway]{$+$} (G2) -- (G3) node[midway,below=3.5em] (F) 
    {$ \displaystyle 
        F = \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{ZW}}}
        {\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{IN}}}
        = \frac{\frac{1}{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\xq_\mb{j} - \xq_{\bullet\bullet})^2}
        {\frac{1}{N-k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{ij}-\xq_{\bullet j})^2}
    $};
    \foreach \X/\Y in {2,3} {\draw[-latex] (G\X) -- (F);}

    \draw[double arrow=10pt colored by blue!50!white and red!50!white,opacity=0.75] (mat2-1-1.north) to[in=80,out=30]  (xpp.north);
    \draw[double arrow=10pt colored by blue!50!white and red!50!white,opacity=0.75] ([yshift=2pt]mat3-1-1.north) to[in=20,out=160] (mat2-1-1.north);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

## ***First attempts with partial information***

I have tried to figure out what it could be your desired output. For this purpose:

- I have defined the command `\tikznode[..options..]{..label..}{..contents..}` in the preamble, which is the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/89320) by [gernot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/110998/gernot) to [How to add arrow in equations and matrix?,to mark the contents you want to join with arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361375/how-to-add-arrow-in-equations-and-matrix). The main reason is that the [`tikzmark`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf) library did not work in my case:

  ```
  \newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
  {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
  \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
   }
  ```
- I have also added following the `arrows, arrows.meta, calc` tikzlibraries.

To your questions:

1. I have placed the equation `F` between the matrices and commented `%\displaystyle` so that it passes between the uppermost two arrows:

   ```
   \coordinate (aux) at ($ (mat1) !.5! (mat2) $);
   \node[anchor=center,](F) at (mat1 |- aux) {$ %\displaystyle 
       F = \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{ZW}}}
       {\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{IN}}}
       = \frac{\frac{1}{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\xq_\mb{j} - \tikznode{xpp2}{$\xq_{\bullet\bullet}$})^2}
       {\frac{1}{N-k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{ij}-\xq_{\bullet j})^2}
       $};
   ```
2. There are  two `$\xq_{\bullet \bullet}$` (I mean `$\bar{x}_{\bullet \bullet}$`). Which one do you mean? The matrix (red arrow) or the equation (orange arrow) one?

**Could you please specify or better include an image of your desired output?**

## My second attempt:

1st improvements:

- Direct referencing the matrix cells with `matname-rownumber-columnnumber` instead of `\tikznode`, which is the approach/solution of [Andrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495959/89320) (with your permission of course)
- Added `round corners` and the arrows go around the matrices for better readability

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, calc, tikzmark}

\newcommand{\mb}[1]{{\bullet #1}} % mean with bullet; dbl brackets to maintain subscript
\newcommand{\xq}{\bar{x}}

    %Tikznode -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/89320
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
%-----

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]

    \matrix [anchor=center,matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat1) {
      x_{11} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{1j} & \ldots & x_{1k} \\ 
      x_{22} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2j} & \ldots & x_{2k} \\ 
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\ 
      x_{i1} & x_{i2} & \ldots & x_{ij} & \ldots & x_{ik} \\ 
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \ldots & x_{nj} & \ldots & x_{nk} \\
    };


    \matrix[anchor=center,matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter= ), below=7em of mat1, xshift=-8em] (mat2) {
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
      \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
      \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
    };

    \node[anchor=west] (xpp) at (mat2.south east){$\overline{x}_{\bullet \bullet} $};


    \matrix[anchor=center,matrix of math nodes, right=4em of mat2, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat3) {
      r_{11} & r_{12} & \ldots & r_{1j} & \ldots & r_{1k} \\
      r_{21} & r_{22} & \ldots & r_{2j} & \ldots & r_{2k} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      r_{i1} & r_{i2} & \ldots & r_{ij} & \ldots & r_{ik} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      r_{n1} & r_{n2} & \ldots & r_{nj} & \ldots & r_{nk} \\
    };

    \coordinate (aux) at ($ (mat1) !.5! (mat2) $);
    \node[anchor=center,](F) at (mat1 |- aux) {$ %\displaystyle 
        F = \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{ZW}}}
        {\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{IN}}}
        = \frac{\frac{1}{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\xq_\mb{j} - \tikznode{xpp2}{$\xq_{\bullet\bullet}$})^2}
        {\frac{1}{N-k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{ij}-\xq_{\bullet j})^2}
        $};
     %                      
    \foreach \X/\Y in {2/{\mathrm{IN}},3/{\mathrm{ZW}}}
    {\draw[-latex] (mat1.south) -- ++(0,-1.5em) -|  ([yshift=0.1em]mat\X.north);
     \draw[-latex] (mat\X.south) -- ++ (0,-4em) node[below] (G\X) {$\widehat{\sigma}^2_{\Y}$};}
     \path (mat2) -- (mat3) node[midway]{$+$} (G2) -- (G3) node[midway,below=3.5em] {}; %(F)

    \draw[latex'-latex',red,rounded corners=2mm] (mat2-1-1.north) -- +(0,0.4) -|(xpp.north);
    \draw[latex'-latex',red,rounded corners=2mm] (mat2-1-1.north) -- +(0,0.4) -|(mat3-1-1.north);
    \draw[latex'-latex',orange,rounded corners=2mm] (mat2-1-1.north)-- +(0,2.25) -| (xpp2.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## My first attempt:

Output:
[image]
Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, calc}

\newcommand{\mb}[1]{{\bullet #1}} % mean with bullet; dbl brackets to maintain subscript
\newcommand{\xq}{\bar{x}}

%Tikznode -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/89320
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
%-----

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix [anchor=center,matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat1) {
      x_{11} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{1j} & \ldots & x_{1k} \\ 
      x_{22} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2j} & \ldots & x_{2k} \\ 
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\ 
      x_{i1} & x_{i2} & \ldots & x_{ij} & \ldots & x_{ik} \\ 
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \ldots & x_{nj} & \ldots & x_{nk} \\
    };


    \matrix[anchor=center,matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter= ), below=7em of mat1, xshift=-8em] (mat2) {
      \tikznode{xp1}{$\xq_\mb{1}$} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
      \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
      \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
    };

    \node[anchor=west] at (mat2.south east){\tikznode{xpp}{$\overline{x}_{\bullet \bullet} $}};


    \matrix[anchor=center,matrix of math nodes, right=4em of mat2, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat3) {
      \tikznode{r11}{$r_{11}$} & r_{12} & \ldots & r_{1j} & \ldots & r_{1k} \\
      r_{21} & r_{22} & \ldots & r_{2j} & \ldots & r_{2k} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      r_{i1} & r_{i2} & \ldots & r_{ij} & \ldots & r_{ik} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      r_{n1} & r_{n2} & \ldots & r_{nj} & \ldots & r_{nk} \\
    };

    \coordinate (aux) at ($ (mat1) !.5! (mat2) $);
    \node[anchor=center,](F) at (mat1 |- aux) {$ %\displaystyle 
    F = \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{ZW}}}
    {\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{IN}}}
    = \frac{\frac{1}{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\xq_\mb{j} - \tikznode{xpp2}{$\xq_{\bullet\bullet})^2$}}
    {\frac{1}{N-k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{ij}-\xq_{\bullet j})^2}
    $};


    \foreach \X/\Y in {2/{\mathrm{IN}},3/{\mathrm{ZW}}}
    {\draw[-latex] (mat1.south) -- ++(0,-1.5em) -|  ([yshift=0.4em]mat\X.north);
     \draw[-latex] (mat\X.south) -- ++ (0,-4em) node[below] (G\X) {$\widehat{\sigma}^2_{\Y}$};}
     \path (mat2) -- (mat3) node[midway]{$+$} (G2) -- (G3) node[midway,below=3.5em] {}; %(F)

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[latex'-latex',red] (xp1)--(xpp);
    \draw[latex'-latex',red] (xp1.north) |- +(0,0.4) -|(r11.north);
    \draw[latex'-latex',orange] (xp1)--(xpp2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no need to use a `\tikznode` in a TikZ matrix (and in some cases could lead to errors), you can simply reference the cell with `matname-rownumber-columnnumber`, for example `mat1-1-1`, or adding `|[name=nodename]|` before the cell content, for example `|[name=r11]|r_11`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I was editing my answer and after posting it I saw Andre´s one with this easy referencing. One learn always new things :)

Comment: Yes, there's always something to learn on TeX.SE! :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX, what about referencing the equation´s term `$\bar{x}_{\bullet \bullet}$` with the matrix´s term? With `tikzmark` I get `Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate. ...\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{ij}-\xq_{\bullet j})^2}`, but it works with `tikznode`. Then using `tikznode` and the matrix cell referencing, i.e., adding `\draw[latex'-latex',orange] (mat2-1-1)--(xpp2);` to the same `tikzpicture` or just to a new `tikzpicture` with `[remember picture,overlay]` it does not give the desired output

Comment: To name an ordinary node you should do:
`\node[anchor=west] (xpp) at (mat2.south east){$\overline{x}_{\bullet \bullet}$};` or
`\node[anchor=west, name=xpp] at (mat2.south east){$\overline{x}_{\bullet \bullet}$};` (hoping to have underdstood what you asked).

Comment: @CarLaTeX, not really. I mean the orange arrow between the `$\bar{x}_{\bullet \bullet}$` (that is `$\xq_{\bullet \bullet}$`) of the `F` equation and the `$\bar{x}_{\bullet 1}$ ` (that is `$\xq_{\bullet 1}$`) of matrix 1. Which is the best way to reference a equation´s term in this case?

Comment: Hi guys! Thank you people so so much for your input. You have helped me out already so much and your suggestions actually look much nicer than what I had imagined. 

I have edited my question now with a rough idea of the output but as I have said your suggestions actually look way nicer plus you have also included the double arrow, which is pretty important to me. 

Also, I have now included the desired equation in between the arrows (Sorry I forgot to be explicit about which equation should be included). 

Thank you guys one more time so much. :)

Comment: You can't reference because you have to put `[remember picture]` also in the first picture, see here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qgfqrjmptkhm. To tell the true, in this case, you can use only one `tikzpicture` environment, without `[remember picture]` at all.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thanks for the explanation. I have found by myself these two key points. In my second approach I have added `remember picture` and in the third one I have deleted it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Ñako Sorry for not having replied early but I had no time before. Btw, +1!

Comment: @Nako Thank you so much for your hard work and so many attempts. 

Do you know how I can specify the arrows to make them look smaller and more elegant just as they were in your second attempt but with everything else staying the same? So just instead of using this big, bright arrows I would like to use small, red double arrows? 
Also, the equation that you have inserted in your third attempt in between the two arrows should stay in place. 

Thank you and 1+ definitely

Comment: @Ñako  Thank you! That is so logical somehow if you explain it. My professor told me to draw the double arrow using <-->. However, if I try that I get the warning: Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind '->'. \draw[red, double,<-->]. 

So obviously, he was not right about that code. Do you have any idea? So I basically just want the tip to show in both directions ( like <--> ) if you know what I mean lol.

Comment: @NoName. Sorry, It was a little confusing to me, what does `double arrow` mean to you; an arrow with two lines (see your desired output) or an arrow with two heads? At the end both. You have a typo, you can draw the double headed arrow using `<->` (only one minus), but not with `<-->` (two minus). I have edited the last (fourth) attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by "inserting the equation" in (1) but the arrows you can draw using the node coordinates of the matrices. For example, the `\bar{x}_{\bullet 1}` entry is the node `(mat2-1-1)` and the `r_{11}` entry is `(mat3-1-1)`. Below I have named the `\bar{x}_{\bullet \bullet}` entry `BB` so you can draw a double red line from `r_{11}` to `\bar{x}_{\bullet \bullet}` using

```
  \draw[red, double,->](mat2-1-1)--(BB);
```

I am not sure if this is really what you want however as the arrow will go through the other matrix entries. Instead, if you use

```
\draw[red, double,->](mat3-1-1) to[out=150,in=30] (mat2-1-1);
```

the the arrow will go around the matrices. The code below gives red and blue arrows to give you different options:

[image]

If you can explain in more detail what you want for (1) I will try and answer that too. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\newcommand{\mb}[1]{{\bullet #1}} % mean with bullet; dbl brackets to maintain subscript
\newcommand{\xq}{\bar{x}}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat1) {
      x_{11} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{1j} & \ldots & x_{1k} \\
      x_{22} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2j} & \ldots & x_{2k} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      x_{i1} & x_{i2} & \ldots & x_{ij} & \ldots & x_{ik} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \ldots & x_{nj} & \ldots & x_{nk} \\
    };

    \matrix[matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter= ),
             below=7em of mat1, xshift=-8em] (mat2) {
      \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
    \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
    \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\
    \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
    \vdots     & \vdots     &        & \vdots     &        & \vdots     \\
    \xq_\mb{1} & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{2} & \ldots & \xq_\mb{j} \\
  };

  \node[anchor=west] (BB) at (mat2.south east){$\overline{x}_{\bullet \bullet} $};
  \matrix[matrix of math nodes, right=4em of mat2, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] (mat3) {
    r_{11} & r_{12} & \ldots & r_{1j} & \ldots & r_{1k} \\
      r_{21} & r_{22} & \ldots & r_{2j} & \ldots & r_{2k} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      r_{i1} & r_{i2} & \ldots & r_{ij} & \ldots & r_{ik} \\
      \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots \\
      r_{n1} & r_{n2} & \ldots & r_{nj} & \ldots & r_{nk} \\
    };

  \foreach \X/\Y in {2/{\mathrm{IN}},3/{\mathrm{ZW}}} {
   \draw[-latex] (mat1) -- (mat\X);
   \draw[-latex] (mat\X.south) -- ++ (0,-4em) node[below] (G\X)
                 {$\widehat{\sigma}^2_{\Y}$};
                 }
   \path (mat2) -- (mat3) node[midway]{$+$} (G2) -- (G3) node[midway,below=3.5em] (F)
  {$ \displaystyle
  F = \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{ZW}}}
           {\hat{\sigma}^2_{\mathrm{IN}}}
    = \frac{\frac{1}{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\xq_\mb{j} - \xq_{\bullet\bullet})^2}
           {\frac{1}{N-k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (  x_{ij}   - \xq_{\bullet j})^2}
  $};

  \foreach \X/\Y in {2,3}
     {\draw[-latex] (G\X) -- (F);}

  \draw[red, double,->](mat2-1-1)--(BB);
  \draw[red, double,->](mat3-1-1)--(mat2-1-1);

  \draw[blue, double,->](mat2-1-1) to[out=210, in=150] (mat2-6-1.south west) to[out=330, in=190] (BB);
  \draw[blue, double,->](mat3-1-1) to[out=150,in=30] (mat2-1-1);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess "inserting the equation" means something like this `----- equation here --->`