# redeclare an arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

As you know, I'm adding more arrows to the code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80090/13482) (maybe tomorrow). At this point, I'd like to overwrite the arrows declarations so that one can simply write `-latex` instead of `-latex new`, but `TikZ` gives me an error because the arrow names have already been used. Is there a way to bypass this behaviour and redefine an arrow tip?

Example of code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{space}{space}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.88pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{0pt}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-space] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would define your arrows with unique names and then give the user the option of substituting them for the original names at the top level.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I'm following your advice.

Comment: I hope that this means you're packaging your arrows into a proper package.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, I edited all the available arrow tips, except for almost 0d ones (like line caps) and implies, and I wrote to Till Tantau. Now I'm waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not recommended but you can bypass the *already defined?* test.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\def\pgf@arrows@check@already#1#2#3{%
   {#3}%
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{space}{space}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.88pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{0pt}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-space] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Maybe this is the right way. I don't know if there are any collateral effects. I think I'll reactivate the "already defined" definition at the end of the code. Thanks

Comment: do you think I should leave the code as is (i.e. with the `latex new` arrow)?

Comment: @Luigi It seems that this is the only sanity check regarding the definition of the arrow so my humble opinion is that this is a risk that one can take but then again it's just me ;)