# New TikZ arrowhead

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm looking how to use currarrow as a new arrowhead in tikz.

Especially it's of the same size of `latex` or `stealth` and way smaller than `triangle 45`.

Any idea how to make it?

For now I use `node[currarrow, sloped,  allow upside down, pos=1] {}` which is not really convenient...

[image]

Comment: Can you add some details about this `currarrow`?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, please specify what you mean by currarrow; a picture would help.

Comment: First of all, I think you can have a look to [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461/13304): perhaps, what you're looking for has already been done by the fantastic library from Luigi.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot but I meant where it is defined, how do you use it etc.

Comment: The context of the question is : when I have a dipole in circuitikz, how to display a voltage arrow between those two points, as there is no component between them?

Answer (score 3):

A quick conceptual definition with hard coded values, you can combine it with Luigi's goodies. It won't work with different line widths etc. since I didn't do any `right/left extend` calculation.

I took the currarrow definition from `circutikz` library. It doesn't look too different from the scaled `triangle 45`. I would recommend using Luigi's definitions and modifiying them if necessary.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{mycurrarrow}{mycurrarrow}{
\pgfarrowsleftextend{-5\pgflinewidth}
\pgfarrowsrightextend{5\pgflinewidth}
}
{
            \newlength\pgf@my@length
            \pgf@my@length = 1cm
            \divide \pgf@my@length by 16
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@my@length}{0pt}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@my@length}{-.8\pgf@my@length}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1\pgf@my@length}{0pt}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@my@length}{.8\pgf@my@length}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@my@length}{0pt}}           
            \pgfusepathqfillstroke
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[mycurrarrow-mycurrarrow,blue] (0,0) -- (2,1);
    \draw[latex-latex,shift={(0mm,3mm)}] (0,0) -- (2,1);
    \draw[triangle 45-triangle 45,shift={(0mm,-3mm)},red] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't get why you don't post five lines of code(four being `documentclass` and `begin/end document` and `circutikz` package)for an example instead of describing the arrow with screenshot from the manual.

Comment: When using your solution with `dashed`, there is the problem of having the arrowhead also in dash mode...

Like in `\draw[-mycurrarrow,dashed] (0,0) -- (2,0);`