# Making arrow heads smaller using "arrowsnew"

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, arrows

I want to make the arrowheads smaller on the `$\delta v_A$` arrow and on the `[<->]` arrows.

I made the file from this post

[Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf)

but it didn't work. I added `\input{arrowsnew}` to the preamble and everything.

So, how can I make the arrow heads smaller?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings, calc, fadings, decorations.pathreplacing, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45]
  \draw[dashdotted] (3.5,0) -- (-5,0);
    \filldraw[top color = green!75!blue, bottom color = blue!40!green] (0,0) circle (.15cm);
      \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.265 with {\arrow{>}},} ]
        \draw[postaction = decorate] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \node[draw, circle, fill = white, inner sep = .08cm, scale = .75]
        at (-.173648,-.984808) {1};
        \filldraw[black] (1,0) circle (.05cm);
        \draw[->] (1.2,-.25) -- (1.2,.5) node[above, scale = .75] {$\Delta v_A$};
        \draw[<->] (-.106066,.106066) -- (-.707107,.707107);
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Go on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3600356&group_id=142562&atid=752795), download the two `.new.code.tex` files and put them in a place where LaTeX can find them (e.g. the same directory of your source code). Then add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.new}` to your preamble and follow the doc (pgfmanual - new section.pdf or test.pdf).

Comment: @Luigi so I will have to put these tex files in every folder then? I have different folders for different classes and I use tikz in every document in every class.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. You can put those files in your personal tree, so that LaTeX can always find them. I just made an example in the previous comment thinking it was the simplest thing to do for a quick test. Let me know if it's all right and keep in mind that it's an unofficial library at the moment.

Comment: @dustin Any update? Could you use the `arrows.new` library?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel everything works fine now.