# Change arrowhead in line style definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm trying to define a size for the arrowhead of a style, like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [line/.style={draw, ->, >=stealth, arrowhead=1cm}]
    % define nodes
    ...
    % define links
    \path[line] (node1) -- (node2)
    ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, tikz complains that it does not understand `arrowhead` inside style definition. What is the correct syntax for customizing the arrowhead of a style?

P.S. I looked at the answers in [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf), but none of them customizes the arrow head inside a style.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the files

- [`pgflibraryarrows.new.code.tex`](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/_discuss/thread/d0a57d64/c67b/attachment/pgflibraryarrows.new.code.tex) and
- [`tikzlibraryarrows.new.code.tex`](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/_discuss/thread/d0a57d64/095c/attachment/tikzlibraryarrows.new.code.tex).

You can then load the new arrow tip definitions with

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.new}
```

which allows you to use the `arrow head` option.

The effect of which are only visible if you actually use the new arrow head tips. In your case, this would be `-stealth new` or `>=stealth new` (but it doesn’t make sense to use `->` and set `>` in the same style as you could just as well write `-stealth new`).