# Making the size of the arrow head proportional to the magnitude of a vector field in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows

Consider a scaled vector field `v = (-x, 2x+y-1)` living on the triangle at (0,1), (1,0), and (0,0):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,1);

\draw[thick] ($(A)$) -- ($(B)$) -- ($(C)$)-- cycle;
\foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 10}
\foreach \y in {0, 1, ..., \x}
{\draw [-stealth,blue] ($(B)-(0.1,0)+0.1*(1-\x,\y)$) 
-- ++(0.02*\x - 0.2, -0.04*\x + 0.4 +0.02*\y-0.2);} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image: tikz]

Comparing with the vector fields drawn by MATLAB's `quiver`:

[image: matlab]

The MATLAB's `quiver` command automatically scales the size of the arrow heads according to the magnitude of the vector.

So my question is: how do we scale the size of the arrow heads in `TikZ`? Preferably in MATLAB's solution, the vector field vanishes at `(0,1)` so there is no arrow there.

For example I googled a little bit, and wonder if `pgfmath` could do some calculation about the length variable `\l`. Then doing something like will work:

```
\draw [-stealth,blue, single arrow head extend=\l mm] ($(B)-(0.1,0)+0.1*(1-\x,\y)$) 
-- ++(0.02*\x - 0.2, -0.04*\x + 0.4 +0.02*\y-0.2);
```

Thanks.

Comment: The arrow tip’s size is usually defined in dependence of the line width. One answer of [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461) should help here.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you sir. That's very informative. How to put some calculated length into the option of the `\draw` command? For example `\draw [-stealth,blue, single arrow head extend=\x mm]`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you so much sir, I have used that new arrow library to make up an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use PGFPlots' `quiver` functionality together with a bit of coordinate filtering to achieve this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90},
    axis equal image,
    hide axis, clip=false
]
\addplot3 [
    blue,
    point meta={sqrt(x^2+(2*x+y-1)^2)},
    quiver={
        u={-x}, v={2*x+y-1},
        scale arrows=0.1,
        every arrow/.append style={
            line width=2pt*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000,
            -latex
        },
    },
    samples=10,
    domain=0:1, y domain=0:1,
    y filter/.append code={\pgfmathparse{(x+y)>1 ? nan : y}},
    x filter/.append code={\pgfmathparse{(sqrt(x^2+(2*x+y-1)^2))==0 ? nan : x}}
] (x,y,0);

\draw (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:0,1) -- cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. :) If there is no other pure `TikZ` solutions, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao: what do you mean with _pure_ TikZ? Pgfplots is built as an extension of TikZ so...

Comment: How to use `quiver`? I'm getting the error *pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/quiver' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ] (x,y,0);*

Comment: @Sigur: You may be using an old version of PGFPlots, I think you need at least version 1.4 for the `quiver` plots.

Comment: @Jake, thanks. I've installed the newer one and it's working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Qrrbrbirlbel's comment I have come up with my own solution as well besides the nice answer using `quiver` by Jake. I am using the `New arrows library` in this question made by Luigi (and it is great!): [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf)

You can download the two `.tex` files in the sourceforge link Luigi gave, and put them in the same directory of your main file then you can compile it using `pdflatex` or `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.new}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,1);
\draw[thick] ($(A)$) -- ($(B)$) -- ($(C)$)-- cycle;

\foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 10}
\foreach \y in {0, 1, ..., \x}
{\pgfmathsetmacro\arrowHeadsize{sqrt(0.1*(-0.2*\x + 0.1*\y+1)*(-0.2*\x + 0.1*\y+1)
                                 +0.1*(1-0.1*\x)*(1-0.1*\x))}
\draw [thick, -stealth new, blue, arrow head=\arrowHeadsize cm] 
($(B)-(0.1,0)+0.1*(1-\x,\y)$) 
 -- ++(0.02*\x - 0.2, -0.04*\x + 0.4 +0.02*\y-0.2);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image: scaled]

A major difference between above solution with the solution using PGFplots's `quiver` is that, by default, `quiver` scales the thickness of the arrow's body as well, here using this approach the arrow thickness is unchanged, only the size of the arrow heads are changed.