# Plot colormap of absolute value of a vector field with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, plot

Using [matlab](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matlab) you can plot the absolute value of a vector field as a colormap to indicate the strength of the field at a given point. The result would look like this:

[image: matlab plot]
(Source code: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/18774/11911)

Is it possible to do similar colormaps plots with pgfplots or another LaTeX plotting library? How to do it?

**Edit**

For answer just consider a simple example of a vector field like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2,
xmax=2,
ymin=-2,
ymax=2,
view={0}{90}
]
\addplot3
[
samples=15,
->,
quiver={
  u={y},
  v={x},
  scale arrows=0.3,   
},
] {0};
%% Corresponding colormap is missing
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, yes, it is. However, you need some input like a vector field or some function that determines the vector field. Do you have an example?

Comment: I added an example. Which vector field to use doesn't matter in this question.

Comment: However if someone reproduces the matlab picture with pgfplots including the varying arrow thickness, I consider to award 100 bounty points for that :-)

Comment: The arrow thickness is easy to achieve: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134169. I guess the bigger problem might be to get function in, unless I misread the posts you link to they solve a differential equation numerically for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one? (Compiling with `lualatex` speeds up things considerably.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/colormap={jet}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,128) rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,255)
rgb255(3cm)=(0,255,255) rgb255(5cm)=(255,255,0) rgb255(7cm)=(255,0,0)
rgb255(8cm)=(128,0,0)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2,view={0}{90},
    colormap/jet]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,samples=101,point meta=-z]{min(sqrt(x*x+y*y),2.2)};
\addplot3
[samples=14,-stealth,quiver={u={y},v={x},scale arrows=0.3,}] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can play with `point meta max` and `point meta min`, but I think the `jet` colormap is very close to what MatLab has.  Together with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134169) one can cook up e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/colormap={jet}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,128) rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,255)
rgb255(3cm)=(0,255,255) rgb255(5cm)=(255,255,0) rgb255(7cm)=(255,0,0)
rgb255(8cm)=(128,0,0)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2,view={0}{90},
    colormap/jet]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,samples=101,point meta=z]{2.2-min(sqrt(x*x+y*y),2.2)};
\addplot3[samples=24,
point meta={min(sqrt(x*x+y*y),2.2)},
quiver={u={y},v={x},scale arrows=0.18,
every arrow/.append style={%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134169
            line width=1.5pt*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000,
            -stealth
        },
}] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think the main challenge for plotting "realistic" vector fields is not so much the presentation but solving the field equations to have some nice functions that can be fed in.