# Scaling arrows in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I followed the link to [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/73/?page=2)
from
[Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80090/22413).  The last comment by left by Till Tantau led me to believe that I could implement code where I change the arrow size.  So, I updated my TikZ packages from CVS.

Then I tried to rescale the arrows.  This is what I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3in,0);
  \draw[arrows=-{stealth[width=1cm,length=1cm]}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the code neither raises any errors nor does it seem to have any effect.  Has anyone else tried to resize their arrows using the most recent CVS TikZ package?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to follow the documentation in section 16.3 on `Arrow keys`.
In fact, if I try to follow the example in the manual a bit more strictly, using `Stealth` instead of `stealth` I get an error message.

Comment: If I **a)** load the `arrows.meta` library and **b)** change `stealth` to `Stealth`, it works. (By the way, it raises error with my code but I may have a newer version than you had when you asked the question.)

Comment: Solved by pgf/TikZ update to v3.0.0.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved with a package update.

Comment: What is the difference between `stealth` and `Stealth`?