# How to customize the arrows of this flowchart?

Tags: formatting, tikz-arrows, charts

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
  % Define block styles
 \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=white!20, 
text width=5.5em, text badly centered, node distance=5cm, inner sep=0pt]
 \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, 
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=5cm,
minimum height=5em]

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (sume) {1.-Sume variables de holgura (forma estándar)};
\node [block, below of=sume] (calcu) {2.-Calcule una primer solución básica factible};
\node [decision, below of=calcu] (decide) {3.-¿Existe una solución básica factible adyacente que sea mejor?};
\node [block, right of=decide, node distance=5cm] (no) {5.-Entonces la solucion basica factible actual es óptima};
\node [block, left of=decide, node distance=5cm] (yes) {4.-Entonces calcule el valor de la funcion $Z$ para la nueva solucion básica factible};


% Draw edges
\path [line] (sume) -- (calcu);
\path [line] (calcu) -- (decide);    
\path [line] (decide) -- node {Si} (yes);
\path [line] (yes) -| (calcu);    
\path [line] (decide) -- node {No} (no);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: I want to create this flowchart]

**This is the first time I'll create a flowchart in Latex, I did this so far, and the result looks terrible. Can someone help me to make this look similar to the image I have?.**

[image]

1. **This is the result from what I did, the problem is that the arrow that goes from 4 to 2 is flip, How can I solve that**
2. **What instruction makes the arrow look thicker?**

Comment: Please reduce your code and ask specific questions! For example: "How do I change the arrow head between these two nodes?" Like this, it is more a code review or do-it-for-me question which does not show much effort. What have you tried? Where are your problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this be what you seek?

1. the problem is that the arrow that goes from 4 to 2 is flip, How can I solve that

   `\path [line] (yes.west) --+(-1cm,0) |- (h);  %` draw from `(yes.west)` to the left 1cm and then go vertically up and horizontally to `(h)` point where the code uses `node` to define `(h)`
2. What instruction makes the arrow look thicker? Modify the `line` style defined in the tizstyle to add `thick`, or `very thick`, or `line width=xx pt`
3. Please check [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/34618)
4. If your question about making the arrow look thicker is about the arrowhead then please check [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461/34618)

yields image below

[image]
Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows,calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
  % Define block styles
 \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=white!20, 
text width=3cm, text badly centered, node distance=5cm, inner sep=0pt]
 \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, 
text width=3cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
minimum height=5em]

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (sume) {1.-Sume variables de holgura (forma estándar)};
\node [block, below of=sume] (calcu) {2.-Calcule una primer solución básica factible};
\node [decision, below of=calcu] (decide) {3.-¿Existe una solución básica factible adyacente que sea mejor?};
\node [block, below right =1cm and 1 cm of decide, node distance=5cm] (no) {5.-Entonces la solucion basica factible actual es óptima};
\node [block, below left = 1cm and 1cm of decide, node distance=5cm] (yes) {4.-Entonces calcule el valor de la funcion $Z$ para la nueva solucion básica factible};


% Draw edges
\path [line] (sume) -- (calcu);
\path [line] (calcu) --node[pos=0.5](h){} (decide);    
\path [line] (decide) -| node[pos=0.2,above] {Si} (yes);
\path [line] (yes.west) --+(-1cm,0) |- (h);    
\path [line] (decide) -| node[pos=0.2,above] {No} (no);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```