# Bigger arrowhead

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I am using the tikzlibrary decorations.markings to put arrowhead on arbitrary places on some lines. My code is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with \arrow{#2}}}]
\draw[
    postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.15}{ >},
    ] (0,1) to (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I want to make the arrowhead a bit bigger and a bit thicker. I read some hints in the manual and several questions here but I can't figure out how to implement this in my code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Try this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461/34618

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `arrows.meta` tikz library` and you can tweak lot of things like length, width, scale, scale length, scale width etc.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with \arrow{#2}}}]
\draw[
    postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.15}{>[scale=2,line width=1pt,line join=miter]},
    ] (0,1) to (3,1);
\draw[
    postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.15}{>[scale=1]},
    ] (0,2) to (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more details, refer to pgfmanual, section 16.5, page 203.