# smooth curved arrow in flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I am new to latex with a very little idea in tikzpicture or pgfplots, so you know what would happen...
Please help me with the following flowchart-type diagram. Here the cartesian plot is a regular X vs Y plot that should be generated with a supplied table, for now, with coordinats {(0,0) (1,1)}. Thanks.

[image: FlowChart]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: What would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this be fair for a start... The proposal starts with a couple of `style` definitions, then place the various nodes cetering the polygon via `above left`, `below right` etc, etc., lastly, connect the nodes with lines that also has a style definition.

Reference: [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461/34618)

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,shapes.geometric,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{poly7/.style={draw=blue!30,fill=blue!30,minimum size=2cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=7,scale=0.5},
rect/.style={draw=blue!20, fill=blue!20,rectangle, minimum height=1cm,rounded corners},
line/.style={draw,solid,line width=2mm,-{Latex[length=4mm]},rounded corners}
}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% create the node

\node[poly7] (a) {\color{red} My Text2};
\node[rect, above right=0.3cm and1cm of a] (b) {\color{red} My Text 0};
\node[below left=0.1cm and 1.5cm of a] (c){};
\path[color=blue,line] (b.west) -| node[above right](){\tiny My Text 1} (a.north);
\path[color=green!40!brown,line] (c.west) |- node[above right](){\color{black}\tiny My Text 3} (a.west);
\begin{axis}[scale=0.2,xshift=3cm,yshift=-1cm]
\node(sin) at (axis cs:-1,1){};
\addplot [red]  coordinates{(0,0) (2,2)};
\end{axis}
\path[color=green!40!brown,line] ([xshift=0.1cm]a.east)-- node[above,sloped](){\color{black}\tiny Predict}(sin);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get this error message--**can't find file  tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex'** So I actually couldn't run the code. How to get rid of this error?

Comment: You need to update your tikz to tikz3.0. sorry I should have metioned that.

Comment: I updated accordingly and it's working. Anyway, is there any way to use a linear up gradient color instead of filling it, inside the polygon or rectangle?

Comment: Hi, yes, there is. Could you try to find an example 'Euler diagram missing a part' by searching this site. Use shade, top, bottom keys, easy to learn. Sorry, I am out of my office, without a PC, but a smart phone.