# tikz arrow head not shown

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]in this simple example the arrow head is not drawn. I don't know why. My pgf version is 2.10.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=0.1pt,gray!30]
    (0,0) grid (4,3);
    \draw[fill=black] (1,2) circle (2pt) coordinate(a)
                      node[above left]{$1$}
                      -- ++(0,-1) circle (2pt) coordinate(b) 
                      node[below left]{$2$}
                      -- ++(1,0) circle (2pt)
                      node[below left]{$3$}
                      -- ++(1,0) circle (2pt)
                      node[below left]{$4$};
   \draw[dashed,->] (b) -- ++(1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I see the arrow with your code (using PGF 3.0). Can you provide a screenshot of what you get?

Comment: I also see the arrow tip.

Comment: You're right. I have to zoom in to see it.

Comment: You have to zoom in?

Comment: Yes, in my PDF viewer(Evince) the arrow head only becomes visible when magnifiying to 175%

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was just than an element was too little and the OP needed viewer magnification to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider also using a bigger arrow tip as `>=latex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, >=latex]
    \draw[line width=0.1pt,gray!30]
    (0,0) grid (4,3);
    \draw[fill=black] (1,2) circle (.7pt) coordinate(a)
                      node[above left]{$1$}
                      -- ++(0,-1) circle (.7pt) coordinate(b) 
                      node[below left]{$2$}
                      -- ++(1,0) circle (.7pt)
                      node[below left]{$3$}
                      -- ++(1,0) circle (.7pt)
                      node[below left]{$4$};
   \draw[dashed,->] (b) -- ++(1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also the advanced `arrows.meta` library if one is interested in more adjustments. The library has virtually endless parameters to play with. For example, you can adjust length, width, inset, slope ..etc

See section 16.3.1 of the [documentation](http://ctan.asis.io/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for more details.

Comment: I'm also looking at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf

Comment: `arrows.meta` is not the advanced library by the way. `arrows` is deprecated (but still supported for those who want to use it) and the standard library is now `arrows.meta`.