# Directing Tikz Arrow To Random Points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an arrow like below:

[image]

It is generated using the below code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.3cm, paperwidth=3.3cm, paperheight=3.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.1,0.1}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.2,0.6,0.2}

\def\arrow{
  (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) arc (6.25:120:1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:0.9) [rounded corners=1] -- (130:1.1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:1.3) [sharp corners] -- (120:1.2) arc (120:5.25:1.2)
  [rounded corners=1] -- (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) -- cycle
}




\def\arrows[#1]{         
  \begin{scope}[scale=#1]
    \draw[color=darkred, left color=red, right color=red!60] \arrow;

  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \arrows[1];

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I want to direct the arrow from point **A** to point **B** which can be any two points but I cant because I cant understand how to set the directions for the curved arrow. This figure is taken form tikz example.

Comment: This example is not a "normal" arrow which joins two points, it's a "handmade" drawing which looks like an arrow. I understand you want to use something similar as a "normal" TikZ arrow, then you can look at `arrows.meta` library or questions like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf?lq=1