# How do I change the size of an arrowhead in tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am unable to change the size of an arrowhead, as it takes the default size when i used `<->` here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw (36mm,-0.5mm)--(36mm,0mm)--(36mm,25.4mm)--(36mm,26.9mm)--(37mm,26.9mm)--(37mm,25.4mm)--(40mm,25.4mm)--(40mm,23.9mm)--(37mm,23.9mm)--(37mm,0mm)--(37mm,-0.5mm);

 \draw[|<->|] (34mm,25.4mm)--node[sloped,midway,above]{\scalebox{0.4}{1.5mm}}(34mm,26.9mm);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

here below is the output of the above MWE

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `arrows.meta` library. It offers advanced options for arrow tips.

Comment: I wan to change the size of an arrowhead only. Thank you for your quick comments@TeXnician

Comment: @Biki Teron in preamblee `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \tikzset{>={Latex[width=0.5mm,length=0.5mm]}}`

Comment: @Biki Teron Look here for more details https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one version using the `arrows.meta` library and a specific (arbitrary) length:

[image: arrow]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw (36mm,-0.5mm)--(36mm,0mm)--(36mm,25.4mm)--(36mm,26.9mm)--(37mm,26.9mm)--(37mm,25.4mm)--(40mm,25.4mm)--(40mm,23.9mm)--(37mm,23.9mm)--(37mm,0mm)--(37mm,-0.5mm);

 \draw[|<->|,>={Classical TikZ Rightarrow[length=.25mm]}] (34mm,25.4mm)--node[sloped,midway,above]{\scalebox{0.4}{1.5mm}}(34mm,26.9mm);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```