# Tree like but with more arrows

Tags: graphs

What is the simplest way to obtain the following tree like graph ?

[image]

Comment: what you try so far?

Comment: 2877 reputation points without a MWE? Please look at tikz-cd package

Comment: Low connection so I can't really work with internet but you are both right !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative since the graph is very simple using `tikz-cd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 &  & a &  &  \\
 & b \arrow[ru] &  & c \arrow[lu] &  \\
d \arrow[ru] &  & e \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] &  & f \arrow[lu]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

For the your question you can see this link to modificate the type of the arrows:
[Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf)

Below new example. I have modificated the thick of one arrow.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 &  & a &  &  \\
 & b \arrow[-triangle 90,
        line width=.8mm,ru] &  & c \arrow[lu] &  \\
d \arrow[ru] &  & e \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] &  & f \arrow[lu]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to have thicker arrows ?

Answer (score 7):

The TikZ graphs library can do this quite simply:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[branch right, grow down] 
{a[x=1] <- {{b <- {d[x=-1],e}}, {c <- {e,f[x=1]}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you want the graph to be more compact, like your image, you can reduce the branch width. Since the node adjustments depend on that width too, it's best to use a macro like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\newcommand*{\bw}{.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[branch right=\bw, grow down] 
{a[x=\bw] <- {{b <- {d[x=-\bw],e}}, {c <- {e,f[x=\bw]}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of second code]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use a text difeernt from the name of the node ? I need to put the same texts at different places in the graph.

Comment: @projetmbc No, I don't think you can do that with this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Easy and simple too with a `psmatrix` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% to compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX))

\begin{document}%

\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1cm, colsep=0.9cm]
& &[name=a] a \\
& [name=b] b & & [name=c] c \\
[name=d] d & & [name=e] e & & [name=f] f
\foreach \beg/\targ in {b/a, c/a, d/b, e/b, e/c, f/c}{\ncline[arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesep=3pt]{\beg}{\targ}}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A hurried attempt with MetaPost and its [`boxes`](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpboxes.pdf) package, included in a LuaLaTeX program.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
input boxes;
def junction(suffix a, b) =
    drawarrow a.c -- b.c cutbefore bpath.a cutafter bpath.b;
enddef;
h := 1.25cm; v := 1cm;
beginfig(1);
    forsuffixes z = a, b, c, d, e, f: circleit.z(str z); endfor;
    e.c = origin; f.c = (h, 0) = - d.c;  
    b.c = (-.5h, v); c.c = (.5h, v);
    a.c = (0, 2v);
    drawunboxed(a, b, c, d, e, f);
    junction (b, a); junction(c, a);
    junction(d, b); junction(e, b);
    junction(e, c); junction(f, c);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It could certainly have been more proficiently coded if I had used, for example, the [`metaobj`](https://ctan.org/pkg/metaobj) package, but I don't know it well enough.

Comment: I congratulate you for your answer. I had not used MetaPost for at least ten years ago. +1