# How to draw an Auslander-Reiten quiver?

Tags: pdftex, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Please, help me in typesetting the following diagram, I'm not an expert in drawing with LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, have a look at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf By the way, this is not an Auslander-Reiten quiver, but simply a quiver.

Answer (score 9):

I have used the advice of the excellent user @egreg. You can change the tip of the vectors by looking at this link: [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf).
I believe that the diagram that uses the arrows in that way is from the package `xymatrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge,row sep=small] 
1 \arrow[rd, "\alpha"] \\ & 3 & 4 \arrow[l, "\gamma"'] \\ 
2 \arrow[ru, "\beta"'] \end{tikzcd} 

\end{document}
```

**FIRST ADDENDUM**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}
\newcommand{\pmat}[4]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{pmatrix}}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge,row sep=small] 
1 \arrow[rd, "\pmat{-1}{5}{5}{1}"] \\ & 3 & 4 \arrow[l, "\gamma"'] \\ 
2 \arrow[ru, "\beta"'] \end{tikzcd} 

\end{document}
```

**SECOND ADDENDUM** From a suggestion of @Bernard's comment I have added `psmallmatrix` environment (from `mathtools`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}
\newcommand{\smat}[4]{\begin{psmallmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{psmallmatrix}}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge,row sep=small] 
1 \arrow[rd, near start, "\smat{-1}{5}{5}{1}"] \\ & 3 & 4 \arrow[l, "\gamma"'] \\ 
2 \arrow[ru, "\beta"'] \end{tikzcd} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: it was wonderful. Thank you for your help @egreg

Comment: how can I write matrices instead of alpha, gamma, beta on arrows @egreg ,

Comment: how can I write matrices instead of alfa beta gamma on arrows @sebastiano

Comment: on the same diagram
you could write on the arrows as a matrix.

Comment: no problem @sebastion you are perfect  :)

Comment: @tuce ahahahah I'm not perfect: I want to be the last of the last.

Comment: May I suggest that perhaps the `psmallmatrix` environment (from `mathtools`) would be more appropriate here?

Comment: @Bernard You are always welcome for me. You are authorized to change my code or to add anything.

Comment: @Sebastiano: OK, I'll do it at once.