# Scale tikz down including lines and arrowheads

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, tikzscale, scalebox

I want to scale down a tikzpicture, so it fits on one page. With `[thick,scale=0.6, every node/.style={transform shape}` that works pretty well, except for line thickness and arrowheads. So I was trying to do that with the popular mentioned `arrowhead=6mm` option in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf/161238#161238). 
However Latex doesn't seem to know that command and gives an error. Whats the correct Syntax fpr changing the arrowhead size?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}
\newcommand{\empt}[3]{$#1_{ #2 }^{( #3 )}$}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.6, every node/.style={transform shape},
    >=LaTeX,
    % Styles
    cell/.style={rectangle, rounded corners=5mm, draw},
    operator/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=-0.5pt,minimum height =.25cm,fill = white},
    function/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=1pt,fill = white},
    ct/.style={circle,draw,line width = .75pt,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,inner sep=1pt},
    gt/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum width=7mm,minimum height=6mm,fill = white,inner sep=1pt},
    ArrowC1/.style={rounded corners=.25cm,thick},
    ArrowC2/.style={rounded corners=.5cm,thick},
    ]

\def\names{{"t-2","t-1","t","t+1"}}%
%Start drawing the thing...    

\foreach[evaluate=\x as \i using {div(\x,8)+1}] \x in {-8,0,8}
{
    % set timesteps
    \pgfmathparse{\names[\i]}\edef\t{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\names[\i+1]}\edef\T{\pgfmathresult}

    % Draw the cell: 
    \node [cell, minimum height =4cm, minimum width=6cm] at (0+\x,0){} ;

    % Draw inputs named ibox#
    \node [gt] (ibox1\x) at (0+\x,0) {$ \varphi$};

    % Draw nodes
    \node[ct=lightgray, label=\empt{x}{\t}{i}] (h\x) at (-4+\x,1.5) {};
    \node[ct=NavyBlue, label=180:\empt{x}{\T}{i-1}] (x\x) at (-2.5+\x,-3) {};
    %\node[ct=gray, label=\empt{x}{t}{i}] (h2\x) at (4+\x,1.5) {};
    \coordinate (h2\x) at (4+\x,1.5) {};
    \node[ct=Mahogany, label=\empt{x}{\T}{i+1}] (x2\x) at (2.5+\x,3) {};

    % Start connecting all. 
    \coordinate (low1\x) at (-1+\x,-1) {};
    \coordinate (cen1\x) at (-1.5+\x,0) {};
    \coordinate (top1\x) at (1.5+\x,1.5) {};

    % upper right connectios from activationfunctions
    \draw[-{Latex[arrowhead]}, ArrowC1] (x\x) |- (low1\x) -| (ibox1\x);
    \draw[->, ArrowC1] (h\x) -| (cen1\x);
    \draw[-, ArrowC1] (cen1\x) |- (low1\x); 
    \draw[-, ArrowC1] (ibox1\x) |- (top1\x);        
    \draw[-, ArrowC1] (top1\x) -- (h2\x);   
    \draw[-, ArrowC1] (top1\x) -| (x2\x);       

}

    \node[ct=lightgray, label=\empt{x}{t+1}{i}] (h2end) at (4+8,1.5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The syntax is `-{Latex[length=3mm,width=5mm]}`, not `-{Latex[arrowhead]}`...

Comment: thanks that worked! Also `transform canvas={scale=1.5}` did the job by scaling the entire picture but fucked up the formats with tikzpicutre being in a figure environment

Comment: You can also use `\pgflowlevelsynccm`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.