# Larger slanted arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm looking to write something like `$\longsearrow quad \nearrow$`

how can I achieve this?

p.s. It seems like  this `\newcommand{\bigarrow}{\mbox{\larger$\searrow$}}` doesn't work, or am I doing it wrong?[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to take an `xrightarrow`, make it longer with some phantom text, and rotate it. However, this is not a very clean solution, and the rotating clearly shows the segments of the `xrightarrow`, which does not look good.

An alternative is to use `tikz` to draw two arrows in a coordinate system.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \xrightarrow
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\arrowrotate{\rotatebox[x=0mm,y=20mm]{-35}{$\xrightarrow{\phantom{xxxx}}$} \nearrow}
\def\arrowtikz{\ \tikz{\draw[->] (0.2,0.25) -- (0.5,0); \draw[->] (0.6,0) -- (0.8,0.15);}\ }

\begin{document}
We define some things.

We define $A \arrowrotate B$.

We define $C \arrowtikz D$.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The `xrightarrow` approach can be customized by adjusting the number of `x` characters (for the length of the arrow), the rotate angle (here `-35`), and the vertical position of the first arrow (here `20mm`).

The `tikz` approach can be customized by changing the coordinates, changing the amount of space (here the control space `\` left and right, see [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing)) and possibly the size and shape of the arrow tip (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161238/).

Comment: The 'tikz' approach seems great. Also thanks for the spacing link :) Awesome thanks!