# How to add shading to a node in a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am plotting a graph. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (A) at (0,2) {A};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (B) at (0,0) {B};
\path (A) edge [loop above] node {} (A);
\path (B) edge   [->]           node[above] {} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However I would like it to look more like:

[image: nodes with shading]

How can I add the shading and change the arrow heads to be like the second image?

Comment: for the type of arrows please see - - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf  -- there is such a wide variety to select from so I have not changed the arrows in my answer below

Comment: please see the edit to the answer also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shadows}%<---------------add shadow
%\usepackage{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow] (A) at (0,2) {A};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow] (B) at (0,0) {B};
\path (A) edge [loop above] node {} (A);
\path (B) edge   [->]           node[above] {} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT -- for better control over shading**

[image]

You can also have better control over the color shading by adding the following line to the options of any node in []

```
drop shadow={top color=green,
                bottom color=yellow!40,
                shadow xshift=4pt,
                shadow yshift=-4pt,}
```

Similarly the xshift and yshift give more precise control over the shadow placement

An example is reproduced below--- note-- the shadows can be applied to arrows also

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shadows, shadows.blur}
%\usepackage{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,
        draw=black,
        fill=white, 
        drop shadow={top color=blue,
                    bottom color=blue!40,
                    shadow xshift=2pt,
                    shadow yshift=-2pt,}, 
%       blur shadow={shadow blur steps=1}
        ] 
        (A) at (0,2) {A};
\node[shape=circle,
        draw=black,
        fill=white, 
        drop shadow={top color=green,
                    bottom color=yellow!40,
                    shadow xshift=4pt,
                    shadow yshift=-4pt,}, 
%       blur shadow={shadow blur steps=1}
    ]  
        (B) at (0,0) {B};
\path (A) edge [loop above] node {} (A);
\path (B) edge   [->]           node[above] {} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!