# Drawing arrows showing inwards to indicate a distance

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to show the height in a cross-section: t in the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4vbf.png).
But because it is very short, the arrowheads cross each other.

[image]

But it should be more like this

[image]

My current code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \filldraw[color=black, fill=black] (0,0) rectangle ++(9,0.5) node[pos=.5](gnd){};
            \filldraw[color=black, fill=gray!20] (0,0.5) rectangle ++(9,2.5) node[pos=.5]{\(\varepsilon_r\)};
            \filldraw[color=black, fill=black] (3.5,3) rectangle ++(2,.2) node[pos=.5](cond){};
            \draw[>=triangle 45, <->] (1,0.5) -- (1,3) node[pos=.5,anchor=west](){\(h\)};
            \draw[>=triangle 45, <->] (3.5,3.4) -- ++(2,0) node[pos=.5,anchor=south](){\(W\)};
            \draw[>=triangle 45, <->] (5.7,3) -- ++(0,0.2) node[pos=.5,anchor=west](){\(t\)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:microstrip_geometry}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Tex. For future question please provide the full code with \documentclass{} and preamble etc as MWE, so that others do not have to guess which packages you are loading.

Comment: This may help:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf