# How to create arrows with different sizes in tikz?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have the following chart in tikz, but I'd like to adjust some problems with the arrows:

- I changed the arrow thickness proportionally to the number in the edge, but the arrow head should be according to the arrow thickness. How can I do that?
- The other end of the arrows should start from under the nodes

How should I proceed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, shapes.arrows, arrows, chains, positioning, automata, backgrounds,patterns,fit,petri,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \label{fig:order}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,initial text = {},node distance=1cm and 1cm,every edge/.style={thick,draw}]
  \tikzstyle{place}=[shape=rectangle, rounded corners, align=center,draw=black,fill=black!5]
    \node [place,initial,minimum height=1cm] (start) {Start};
    \node [place,right=of start] (extraction) {Extraction};
    \node [place,right=of extraction] (evaluation) {Evaluation};
    \node [place,right=of evaluation, yshift=1cm] (filtering) {Filtering};
    \node [place,above=of filtering] (enrichment) {Correction/\\enrichment};
    \node [place,right=of filtering, yshift=1cm] (enrichment2) {Correction/\\enrichment};
    \node [place,below=of enrichment2] (evalcorrec) {Evaluation and\\correction/\\enrichment};
    \node [place,below=of evalcorrec] (concurrently) {Filtering and\\ correction/\\enrichment};

    \node [place,above=of enrichment2] (filtering2) {Filtering};
    \node [place,accepting,right=of evalcorrec,minimum height=8cm] (end) {end};
    
    
    \path(filtering2)-|node (f2_end) {}(end.west);
    \path(enrichment)-|node (e_end) {}(end.west);
    \path(enrichment2)-|node (e2_end) {}(end.west);
    \path(filtering)-|node (f_end) {}(end.west);
    \path(concurrently)-|node (c_end) {}(end.west);
    
    
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2.15mm]}] (start) edge[line width=6.125mm] node[above] {125}(extraction);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2.15mm]}] (extraction) edge[line width=4.1mm] node[above] {82}(evaluation) edge[bend right, line width=2.15mm] node[below] {43}(end.south west);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (evaluation) edge[line width=1.05mm] node[above] {21}(filtering) edge[bend right,line width=.5mm] node[above] {10}($(end.west)+(0,-3)$) edge[line width=2.45mm] node[above] {49}(enrichment) edge[line width=0.1mm] node[above] {2}(concurrently);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (enrichment) edge[line width=0.05mm] node[above] {1}(filtering2) edge[line width=2.4mm] node[above] {48}(e_end);
    
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (concurrently) edge[line width=0.1mm] node[above] {2}(c_end);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (filtering) edge[line width=0.2mm] node[above] {4}(enrichment2) edge[line width=0.05mm] node[above] {1}(evalcorrec) edge[line width=0.8mm] node[above] {16}(f_end);
    
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (filtering2) edge[line width=0.05mm] node[above] {1}(f2_end);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (enrichment2) edge[line width=0.2mm] node[above] {4}(e2_end);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (evalcorrec) edge[line width=0.05mm] node[above] {1}(end.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: You don't need to load both `arrows` and `arrows.meta` to draw arrows. The latter in enough and is the prefered one, nowadays. You'll have to look for some explanations on how to use it but it's very versatile. [See a full answer and links here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161238/204164).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a line width factor to the arrow length for example `Latex[length=2.15mm 1]`. I have tried a factor of 1 which you may adapt for your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, shapes.arrows, arrows, chains, positioning, automata, backgrounds,patterns,fit,petri,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \label{fig:order}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,initial text = {},node distance=1cm and 1cm,every edge/.style={thick,draw}]
  \tikzstyle{place}=[shape=rectangle, rounded corners, align=center,draw=black,fill=black!5]
    \node [place,initial,minimum height=1cm] (start) {Start};
    \node [place,right=of start] (extraction) {Extraction};
    \node [place,right=of extraction] (evaluation) {Evaluation};
    \node [place,right=of evaluation, yshift=1cm] (filtering) {Filtering};
    \node [place,above=of filtering] (enrichment) {Correction/\\enrichment};
    \node [place,right=of filtering, yshift=1cm] (enrichment2) {Correction/\\enrichment};
    \node [place,below=of enrichment2] (evalcorrec) {Evaluation and\\correction/\\enrichment};
    \node [place,below=of evalcorrec] (concurrently) {Filtering and\\ correction/\\enrichment};

    \node [place,above=of enrichment2] (filtering2) {Filtering};
    \node [place,accepting,right=of evalcorrec,minimum height=8cm] (end) {end};
    
    
    \path(filtering2)-|node (f2_end) {}(end.west);
    \path(enrichment)-|node (e_end) {}(end.west);
    \path(enrichment2)-|node (e2_end) {}(end.west);
    \path(filtering)-|node (f_end) {}(end.west);
    \path(concurrently)-|node (c_end) {}(end.west);
    
    
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2.15mm 1]}] (start) edge[line width=6.125mm] node[above] {125}(extraction);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2.15mm 1]}] (extraction) edge[line width=4.1mm] node[above] {82}(evaluation) edge[bend right, line width=2.15mm] node[below] {43}(end.south west);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm 1]}] (evaluation) edge[line width=1.05mm] node[above] {21}(filtering) edge[bend right,line width=.5mm] node[above] {10}($(end.west)+(0,-3)$) edge[line width=2.45mm] node[above] {49}(enrichment) edge[line width=0.1mm] node[above] {2}(concurrently);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm 1]}] (enrichment) edge[line width=0.05mm] node[above] {1}(filtering2) edge[line width=2.4mm] node[above] {48}(e_end);
    
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm 1]}] (concurrently) edge[line width=0.1mm] node[above] {2}(c_end);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm 1]}] (filtering) edge[line width=0.2mm] node[above] {4}(enrichment2) edge[line width=0.05mm] node[above] {1}(evalcorrec) edge[line width=0.8mm] node[above] {16}(f_end);
    
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm 1]}] (filtering2) edge[line width=0.05mm] node[above] {1}(f2_end);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm 1]}] (enrichment2) edge[line width=0.2mm] node[above] {4}(e2_end);
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2mm 1]}] (evalcorrec) edge[line width=0.05mm] node[above] {1}(end.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. What about the other end. I'd like to avoid the overlapping of the arrow and the node (like in evaluation and extraction)

Comment: @LuizFernandoPuttowSouthier . You can set some white space around nodes with the use of `out sep=<some distance>` option.

Comment: You mean `outer sep`. An other way is to use `shorten <` on the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

After one year, it still may help you or someone else ...

- For all elements of picture are defined common styles. By this the picture is more consistent and picture code is much shorter-.
- For arrows is used `arrows.meta` library.
- Arrows are placed on background layer.
- Arrows starts are prolonged by `shorten < =-\pgflinewidth`, so they are begid of nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,  
                backgrounds,
                %calc, chains,                   % not used
                %fit,                            % not used
                %patterns,  petri,               % not used
                                 positioning, 
                quotes,
                %shapes.geometric, shapes.arrows % not used
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{that referencing will work properly ...}
\label{fig:order}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm and 7mm,
 accepting/.style = {double distance=2pt},
       arr/.style = {draw, line width=#1/8, shorten < =-\pgflinewidth,
                     -{Triangle[width=#1/8+6pt, length=3mm]}
                    },
every edge quotes/.append style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, inner ysep=1.1ex, sloped},
     place/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw, rounded corners=2pt, fill=gray!10,
                     minimum height=7ex, inner xsep=2.4pt, outer sep=0pt,
                     align=center, font=\small,
                     initial text=
                     }
                    ]
\node (start)   [place,initial]         {Start};
    \begin{scope}[nodes={place, text width=6em}]
\node (extr)    [right=of start]        {Extraction};
\node (eval)    [right=of extr]         {Evaluation};
\node (fltr-1)  [right=of eval]         {Filtering};

\node (ce-1)    [above right=of fltr-1] {Correction/\\enrichment};
\node (ece)     [below right=of fltr-1] {Evaluation and\\correction/\\enrichment};
\node (ce-2)    [above left=of ce-1]    {Correction/\\enrichment};

\node (fce)     [below=of ece]          {Filtering and\\ correction/\\enrichment};

\node (fltr-2)  [above right=of ce-2]   {Filtering};
    \end{scope}
\node (end)     [accepting, place, 
                 minimum height=99mm,
                 below right=0mm and 7mm % 
                 of fltr-2.north east]  {end};
% edges
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[arr=125pt]    (start)     to ["125"]  (extr);
\draw[arr=82pt]     (extr)      to ["82"]   (eval);
\draw[arr=21pt]     (eval)      to ["21"]   (fltr-1);
\draw[arr=16pt]     (fltr-1)    to ["26"]   (fltr-1 -| end.west);
\draw[arr=4pt]      (fltr-1)    to ["4"]    (ce-1);
\draw[arr=1pt]      (fltr-1)    to ["1"]    (ece);

\draw[arr=21pt]     (eval)      to [bend left, "21"]   (ce-2);
\draw[arr=1pt]      (ce-2)      to ["1"]    (fltr-2);
\draw[arr=48pt]     (ce-2)      to ["48"]    (ce-2 -| end.west);
\draw[arr=1pt]     (fltr-2)     to ["1"]   (fltr-2 -| end.west);

\draw[arr=1pt]      (ece)       to ["1"]    (ece -| end.west);
\draw[arr=2pt]      (fce)       to ["2"]    (fce -| end.west);

\draw[arr=10pt]     (eval)      to [out=300, in=180, "10"]  
                                            ([yshift=-7ex] fce -| end.west);
\draw[arr=43pt]     (extr)      to [out=300, in=180, "43"]
                                            ([yshift=-11ex] fce -| end.west);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]