# Error changing arrow tips sizes - TikZ/PGF 3.0.1a

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Good day to everyone. I'm not new to LaTeX but I am to TikZ/PGF. So far I'm willing to change the size of latex arrow head, and according to the `\listfiles` command in the preamble I'm using TikZ 3.0.1a:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
```

Now, when I use the method explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161238/248426) I get an error, unknown key "lenght". Removing it also shows an error regarding "width".

Below an MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(2,2); %This line works, used as control
    
    % UNCOMMENT TO CHECK ERRORS
    %\draw[-{Latex[length=3mm,width=5mm]}] (0,0)--(2,0); %ERROR=Unkown arrow tip kind 'Latex'.
    
    %\draw[-{latex[length=3mm,width=5mm]}] (0,0)--(2,0); %ERROR=I do not know the key 'lenght'
    
    %\draw[-{latex[width=5mm]}] (0,0)--(2,0); %ERROR=I do not know the key 'width'
    
    \draw[-{latex[scale=2]}] (0,-1)--(2,1); %This line works, however it is the same size as the original one
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also used the `scale` method and it runs, but the arrow head remains the same.

Any ideas? I'm using TeXlive from Linux Mint 19 repositories, btw.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but trying to draw arrows using \draw[<->] never works for me. Only if I use text keys such as \draw[stealth-stealth]

Comment: That should work, the difference between the two is, I believe, that `<->` adds the default arrow tip, while `stealth-stealth` adds specifically the `stealth` arrow tip. Anyways, as the answer below and the answer you link to state, you need the `arrows.meta` library. Generally, arrow tips that start with a capital letter are defined by `arrows.meta` and are customizable. Arrow tips starting with a lower case letter are not customizable, and are from either the default set or the deprecated `arrows` library.

Comment: For example `\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \draw [<->] (0,0) -- (1,0); \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}` works fine.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: As a last comment in this, I discovered the `<->` error was a package clash with babel (spanish)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the library `arrows.meta` to use `Latex`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(2,2); 
    \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm,width=5mm]}] (0,0)--(2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!